# C++ performance challenge: integer to std::string conversion

Tags: c++, performance, string, integer

**Can anyone beat the performance of my integer to std::string code, linked below?**

There are already several questions that explain how to convert an integer into a `std::string` in C++, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228005/alternative-to-itoa-for-converting-integer-to-string-c), but none of the solutions provided are efficient.

Here is compile-ready code for some common methods to compete against:

- The "C++ way", using stringstream: http://ideone.com/jh3Sa
- sprintf, which SO-ers usually recommend to the performance conscious: http://ideone.com/82kwR

Contrary to [popular belief](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228005/alternative-to-itoa-for-converting-integer-to-string-c/228041#228041), `boost::lexical_cast` has its own implementation ([white paper](http://www.accu.org/var/uploads/journals/overload74.pdf)) and does not use `stringstream` and numeric insertion operators.  I'd really like to see its performance compared, because [this other question suggests that it's miserable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250795/very-poor-boostlexical-cast-performance).

And my own contribution, which is competitive on desktop computers, and demonstrates an approach that runs at full speed on embedded systems as well, unlike algorithms dependent on integer modulo:

- Ben's algorithms: http://ideone.com/SsEUW

If you want to use that code, I'll make it available under a simplified BSD license (commercial use allowed, attribution required).  Just ask.

Finally, the function `ltoa` is non-standard but widely available.

- ltoa version, for anyone who has a compiler that provides it (ideone doesn't): http://ideone.com/T5Wim

I'll post my performance measurements as an answer shortly.

### Rules for algorithms

- Provide code for a conversion of at least 32-bit signed and unsigned integers into decimal.
- Produce output as a `std::string`.
- No tricks that are incompatible with threading and signals (for example, static buffers).
- You may assume an ASCII character set.
- Make sure to test your code on `INT_MIN` on a two's complement machine where the absolute value is not representable.
- Ideally, the output should be character-for-character identical with the canonical C++ version using `stringstream`, http://ideone.com/jh3Sa, but anything that is clearly understandable as the correct number is ok, too.
- **NEW**: Although you can use whatever compiler and optimizer options (except completely disabled) you want for the comparison, the code needs to also compile and give correct results under at least VC++ 2010 and g++.

### Hoped-for Discussion

Besides better algorithms, I'd also like to get some benchmarks on several different platforms and compilers (let's use MB/s throughput as our standard unit of measure).  I believe that the code for my algorithm (I know the `sprintf` benchmark takes some shortcuts -- now fixed) is well-defined behavior by the standard, at least under the ASCII assumption, but if you see any undefined behavior or inputs for which the output is invalid, please point that out.

### Conclusions:

Different algorithms perform for g++ and VC2010, likely due to the different implementations of `std::string` on each.  VC2010 clearly does a better job with NRVO, getting rid of return-by-value helped only on gcc.

Code was found that outperforms `sprintf` by an order of magnitude.  `ostringstream` falls behind by a factor of 50 and more.

The winner of the challenge is user434507 who produces code that runs 350% of the speed of my own on gcc.  Further entries are closed due to the whims of the SO community.

The current (final?) speed champions are:

- For gcc: Eugene Smith, at 8 times faster than `sprintf`: http://ideone.com/0uhhX
- For Visual C++: Timo, at 15 times faster than `sprintf`: http://ideone.com/VpKO3

Comment: I think this "Question" better fits in here http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Your problem is underspecified, as it doesn't explain how the result string should look like. Most likely, always returning the empty string would not be considered acceptable, but is conforming as the specification stands.

Comment: @Martin: Happy now?  I'm leaving it fairly flexible, although my code removes leading zeros I'd be willing to listen to arguments that performance requires small variations to the format.  BTW, since the performance metric is megabytes of text per second, generating an empty string would score very very poorly.

Comment: I asssume the algorithm is expected to just output a sequence of digits? No thousands separators or other (culture-sensitive) formatting?

Comment: @jalf: Correct.  Digits and possibly a leading minus sign.  There's no penalty for frills, but I can't imagine how they'd help performance.

Comment: @Ben: it's not so much about a penalty for frills, but more what you're trying to achieve. A "superior stringstream" would be *required* to be culture aware and support such customization. But it appears you're only after an efficient implementation of the simplest case? (straight digit to char conversion). Just trying to understand what you're after.

Comment: Your measurement metric seems to favour long numbers (8 and 9 digits) heavily. I think that metric is flawed, because most numbers you encounter in practice are very short numbers, like '0' or '1'. An equal distribution of one to nine digit numbers might be more realistic.

Comment: @drhirsch: Here's a modified testbench that formats every power of 3 that fits in a 32-bit integer (3**0 up to 3**20).  With this data set, [my code gets 40.9 MB/s on ideone](http://ideone.com/2X0s9).  It still dominates [`sprintf`, which falls to 17.2 MB/s](http://ideone.com/82kwR), by a wide margin, actually widening the gap.  But you're right that it may make a significant difference when comparing custom solutions.

Comment: oops, the link for `sprintf` with the power-of-3 testbench should have been http://ideone.com/DFaiS  Also, user434507's latest submission, when [tested against powers-of-3](http://ideone.com/pQbtO), turns out an astounding 120MB/s on ideone.

Comment: I voted to re-open this question, there's no reason for it to be closed.

Comment: On this question, ideone links are mostly dead. Would you please include the code somewhere more reliable?

Comment: @nhahtdh: I have some but not all of the code kept locally, and I'm not sure how it compares version-wise to the code linked from this question and answers.  The ideone site states that code snippets are kept on the site "forever".  I've just e-mailed the ideone team to see if these were removed by mistake and can perhaps be gotten back.

Comment: @BenVoigt, from Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Optimization Reference Manual. Section 10.5 NUMERICAL DATA CONVERSION TO ASCII FORMAT, Page 371 AKA section 10-33. A discussion of how to do division by a constant by multiplication (At 28-30 clocks - 725MBs  using my routine it had to be so. Division would have been an order of magnitude too slow) AND Example 10-22. Conversion of 64-bit Integer to ASCII Using SSE4. http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf  Enjoy!

Comment: @RocketRoy: I'm well aware that division by a constant in *all* of these answers is being done via multiplication.

Comment: `std::string` is slow by itself. if you need performance at some point it makes sense to avoid `std::string` and use `char*`

Comment: @javapowered: `std::string` is only as slow as how you use it.

Comment: can we make this code faster replaceing % and / with http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/div/ ?

Comment: @javapowered: No.  Trust the optimizer.

Comment: @BenVoigt what is the purpose of `div` function then?

Comment: @javapowered: Just a leftover from long long ago when optimizers were really bad.  Or not so long ago, when a processor is brand-new, and there isn't an optimizer for it yet.  But this optimization isn't even that processor-specific.  Finally, optimizing compilers are perfectly capable of replacing a `/`+`%` pair with a call to a library function, if the function is faster.  The real issue here is that the optimizer knows a way to do division by a constant that doesn't actually use the divider hardware (see above comments).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is a kind of contest.

Comment: Gasp! Ideone links all dead! Ben do you happen to have the driver code saved somewhere?

Comment: @BenVoigt I would ask the same. The links are all dead. I would love to take a look at these more closely

Comment: @Steven http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351371/c-performance-challenge-integer-to-stdstring-conversion#comment32461631_4351371

Comment: what the heck happened to ideone links :/

Comment: Ideone broke its own terms of service several years ago, that's what

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a good fit at all for here. If the mods want to keep it, lock it with a "Historical interest" message; as it is it does not belong here.

Comment: @KenY-N: You should back that up with more than just your opinion before asking mods for a lock.  In particular, which rule of site scope do you think is not met?

Comment: Fixing all the links is probably too tedious, but do you mind fixing the links in the conclusion seeing as how that's probably the ones people are most interested in? I'd fix it myself but I fail to find the rumored user434507 version.

Comment: @PasserBy: Unfortunately although I agreed with ideone to make the code available "forever", I don't have any power to force them to respect their own Terms of Service.

Comment: This is why you shouldn't put links without snippet. Can you put back the code or delete your question? It's useless without the answer...

Comment: @MappaM: You are confused, the answers are below and have code (many of them adapted from the code I provided when asking the question), but the question is not the code, the contract is clearly stated here in the question under "Rules for Algorithms".

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
#include <string>

const char digit_pairs[201] = {
  "00010203040506070809"
  "10111213141516171819"
  "20212223242526272829"
  "30313233343536373839"
  "40414243444546474849"
  "50515253545556575859"
  "60616263646566676869"
  "70717273747576777879"
  "80818283848586878889"
  "90919293949596979899"
};


std::string& itostr(int n, std::string& s)
{
    if(n==0)
    {
        s="0";
        return s;
    }

    int sign = -(n<0);
    unsigned int val = (n^sign)-sign;

    int size;
    if(val>=10000)
    {
        if(val>=10000000)
        {
            if(val>=1000000000)
                size=10;
            else if(val>=100000000)
                size=9;
            else 
                size=8;
        }
        else
        {
            if(val>=1000000)
                size=7;
            else if(val>=100000)
                size=6;
            else
                size=5;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        if(val>=100)
        {
            if(val>=1000)
                size=4;
            else
                size=3;
        }
        else
        {
            if(val>=10)
                size=2;
            else
                size=1;
        }
    }
    size -= sign;
    s.resize(size);
    char* c = &s[0];
    if(sign)
        *c='-';

    c += size-1;
    while(val>=100)
    {
       int pos = val % 100;
       val /= 100;
       *(short*)(c-1)=*(short*)(digit_pairs+2*pos); 
       c-=2;
    }
    while(val>0)
    {
        *c--='0' + (val % 10);
        val /= 10;
    }
    return s;
}

std::string& itostr(unsigned val, std::string& s)
{
    if(val==0)
    {
        s="0";
        return s;
    }

    int size;
    if(val>=10000)
    {
        if(val>=10000000)
        {
            if(val>=1000000000)
                size=10;
            else if(val>=100000000)
                size=9;
            else 
                size=8;
        }
        else
        {
            if(val>=1000000)
                size=7;
            else if(val>=100000)
                size=6;
            else
                size=5;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        if(val>=100)
        {
            if(val>=1000)
                size=4;
            else
                size=3;
        }
        else
        {
            if(val>=10)
                size=2;
            else
                size=1;
        }
    }

    s.resize(size);
    char* c = &s[size-1];
    while(val>=100)
    {
       int pos = val % 100;
       val /= 100;
       *(short*)(c-1)=*(short*)(digit_pairs+2*pos); 
       c-=2;
    }
    while(val>0)
    {
        *c--='0' + (val % 10);
        val /= 10;
    }
    return s;
}
```

This will blow up on systems that disallow unaligned memory accesses (in which case, the first unaligned assignment via `*(short*)` would cause a segfault), but should work very nicely otherwise.

One important thing to do is to minimize the use of `std::string`. (Ironic, I know.) In Visual Studio, for example, most calls to methods of std::string are not inlined, even if you specify /Ob2 in compiler options. So even something as trivial as a call to `std::string::clear()`, which you might expect to be very fast, can take 100 clockticks when linking CRT as a static library, and as much as 300 clockticks when linking as a DLL.

For the same reason, returning by reference is better because it avoids an assignment, a constructor and a destructor.

Comment: Thanks for your attempt.  On ideone (http://ideone.com/BCp5r), it scores 18.5 MB/s, about half the speed of `sprintf`.  And with VC++ 2010, it gets about 50 MB/s, about twice the speed of sprintf.

Comment: MB/s is a strange metric, especially seeing how you don't remove trailing whitespaces from the string in your implementations. My updated code runs faster than your implementation with x64 VC++ 2005 on Core i7 920 (16.2M ops/s vs. 14.8M ops/s), _ltoa does 8.5M ops/s and sprintf() does 3.85M ops/s.

Comment: Your code doesn't properly resize the string, mine does (see lines 81, 198, and 290).  I took some shortcuts in the `sprintf` implementation, I already mentioned that in my question, but I believe the code-to-beat gives exactly the same result as stringstream.

Comment: I've fixed the `sprintf` wrapper as well, to avoid confusion.

Comment: BTW, your improved version (http://ideone.com/GLAbS) gets 41.7 MB/s on ideone, and right around 120 MB/s on VC++ 2010 32-bit.

Comment: Remaining fix -- try using the old math function div. On some architectures calling it is faster.

Comment: Ben: what happens if you declare 'val' as int? the only reason for it to be __int64 is to avoid the integer overflow for n=INT_MIN, which is a case that can be handled explicitly. I'd imagine that manipulating a __int64 is costly in 32-bit.

Comment: Joshua: not on Intel. VC2005 compiler is smart enough to replace the division by 10 with integer multiplication, which is THE fastest way to do things here.

Comment: OK, after some more hacking in 32-bit VC2005, I got to the point where two calls to string::resize() (one in the beginning with resize(16) and one in the end with resize(size+sign)) take more time than the actual conversion. It seems that memmove() is being called. This is bizarre...

Comment: The new version is fantastic under gcc.  I had to make a couple small modifications to make it comply with the rules (caller-provided result string instead of global), but get your same great performance.  http://ideone.com/0uhhX  I'll test on VC++ 2010 later and let you know how it performs, but you win as soon as you update your answer to the new version of the code.

Comment: BTW, while I was writing the question, I saw `memmove` appearing in the call tree under VC2010 as well, tracked it down to silly logic in `std::string::erase` when erasing from the tail, and submitted a patch to Microsoft.  Hopefully the next Visual Studio service pack will resize `std::string` much faster.

Comment: But wait, there's more. Incorporating some ideas of yours and timo gets us here: http://ideone.com/UiWKI

Comment: @user434507: Seems safer to just use `memcpy` like Timo did... it's an intrinsic on most compilers, so the unaligned copy will get used on architectures that allow it.  At any rate, there was no speed decrease on ideone: http://ideone.com/VLUco

Comment: `std::string::clear` in Visual Studio is probably affected by the `std::string::erase` problems, since `erase(0, npos)` is a reasonable way to implement clear and avoid code duplication.

Comment: I have posted [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10488468/417501) with a different algorithm.

Comment: For the record, the answer above is the "user434507" algorithm.

Answer (score 23):

Ah, awesome challenge by the way... I've had a lot of fun with this.

I have two algorithms to submit (code is at the bottom if you feel like skipping to it). In my comparisons I require that the function return a string and that it can handle int and unsigned int. Comparing things that don't construct a string to those that do doesn't really make sense.

The first one is a fun implementation that doesn't use any precomputed lookup tables or explicit division/modulo. This one is competitive with the others with gcc and with all but Timo's on msvc (for a good reason that I explain below). The second algorithm is my actual submission for highest performance. In my tests it beats all the others on both gcc and msvc.

I think I know why some of the results on MSVC are very good. std::string has two relevant constructors
`std::string(char* str, size_t n)`

 and 
`std::string(ForwardIterator b, ForwardIterator e)` 
gcc does the same thing for both of them... that is it uses the second to implement the first. The first constructor can be implemented significantly more efficiently than that and MSVC does so. The side benefit of this is that in some cases (like my fast code and Timo's code) the string constructor can be inlined. In fact, just switching between these constructors in MSVC is almost a 2x difference for my code.

My performance testing results:

### Code Sources:

**- [Voigt](http://ideone.com/SsEUW) 

 - [Timo](http://ideone.com/VpKO3) 

 - [ergosys](http://ideone.com/pswq9) 

 - [user434507](http://ideone.com/UiWKI) 

 - [user-voigt-timo](http://ideone.com/VLUco) 

 - [hopman-fun](http://ideone.com/RWmFQ) 

 - [hopman-fast](http://ideone.com/GkPcy)**

### gcc 4.4.5 -O2 on Ubuntu 10.10 64-bit, Core i5

```
hopman_fun: 124.688  MB/sec --- 8.020 s
hopman_fast: 137.552  MB/sec --- 7.270 s
voigt: 120.192  MB/sec --- 8.320 s
user_voigt_timo: 97.9432  MB/sec --- 10.210 s
timo: 120.482  MB/sec --- 8.300 s
user: 97.7517  MB/sec --- 10.230 s
ergosys: 101.42  MB/sec --- 9.860 s
```

### MSVC 2010 64-bit /Ox on Windows 7 64-bit, Core i5

```
hopman_fun: 127  MB/sec --- 7.874 s
hopman_fast: 259  MB/sec --- 3.861 s
voigt: 221.435  MB/sec --- 4.516 s
user_voigt_timo: 195.695  MB/sec --- 5.110 s
timo: 253.165  MB/sec --- 3.950 s
user: 212.63  MB/sec --- 4.703 s
ergosys: 78.0518  MB/sec --- 12.812 s
```

Here are some results and a testing/timing framework on ideone
http://ideone.com/XZRqp 
Note that ideone is a 32-bit environment. Both of my algorithms suffer from that, but hopman_fast is at least still competetive.

Note that for those the two or so that don't construct a string I added the following function template:

```
template <typename T>
std::string itostr(T t) {
    std::string ret;
    itostr(t, ret);
    return ret;
}
```

Now for my code...first the fun one:

```
    // hopman_fun

template <typename T> 
T reduce2(T v) {
    T k = ((v * 410) >> 12) & 0x000F000F000F000Full;
    return (((v - k * 10) << 8) + k);
}

template <typename T>
T reduce4(T v) {
    T k = ((v * 10486) >> 20) & 0xFF000000FFull;
    return reduce2(((v - k * 100) << 16) + (k));
}

typedef unsigned long long ull;
inline ull reduce8(ull v) {
    ull k = ((v * 3518437209u) >> 45);
    return reduce4(((v - k * 10000) << 32) + (k));
}

template <typename T>
std::string itostr(T o) {
    union {
        char str[16];
        unsigned short u2[8];
        unsigned u4[4];
        unsigned long long u8[2];
    };

    unsigned v = o < 0 ? ~o + 1 : o;

    u8[0] = (ull(v) * 3518437209u) >> 45;
    u8[0] = (u8[0] * 28147497672ull);
    u8[1] = v - u2[3] * 100000000;

    u8[1] = reduce8(u8[1]);
    char* f;
    if (u2[3]) {
        u2[3] = reduce2(u2[3]);
        f = str + 6;
    } else {
        unsigned short* k = u4[2] ? u2 + 4 : u2 + 6;
        f = *k ? (char*)k : (char*)(k + 1);
    }
    if (!*f) f++;

    u4[1] |= 0x30303030;
    u4[2] |= 0x30303030;
    u4[3] |= 0x30303030;
    if (o < 0) *--f = '-';
    return std::string(f, (str + 16) - f);
}
```

And then the fast one:

```
    // hopman_fast

struct itostr_helper {
    static unsigned out[10000];

    itostr_helper() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            unsigned v = i;
            char * o = (char*)(out + i);
            o[3] = v % 10 + '0';
            o[2] = (v % 100) / 10 + '0';
            o[1] = (v % 1000) / 100 + '0';
            o[0] = (v % 10000) / 1000;
            if (o[0]) o[0] |= 0x30;
            else if (o[1] != '0') o[0] |= 0x20;
            else if (o[2] != '0') o[0] |= 0x10;
            else o[0] |= 0x00;
        }
    }
};
unsigned itostr_helper::out[10000];

itostr_helper hlp_init;

template <typename T>
std::string itostr(T o) {
    typedef itostr_helper hlp;

    unsigned blocks[3], *b = blocks + 2;
    blocks[0] = o < 0 ? ~o + 1 : o;
    blocks[2] = blocks[0] % 10000; blocks[0] /= 10000;
    blocks[2] = hlp::out[blocks[2]];

    if (blocks[0]) {
        blocks[1] = blocks[0] % 10000; blocks[0] /= 10000;
        blocks[1] = hlp::out[blocks[1]];
        blocks[2] |= 0x30303030;
        b--;
    }

    if (blocks[0]) {
        blocks[0] = hlp::out[blocks[0] % 10000];
        blocks[1] |= 0x30303030;
        b--;
    }

    char* f = ((char*)b);
    f += 3 - (*f >> 4);

    char* str = (char*)blocks;
    if (o < 0) *--f = '-';
    return std::string(f, (str + 12) - f);
}
```

Comment: For those that are interested in how hopman-fun works but don't feel like puzzling it out, I created a commented version at http://ideone.com/rnDxk

Comment: I don't understand how the first one works even with the comments. :D The fast one is really nice, though it has its price in memory usage. But I guess 40kB is still acceptable. I actually modified my own code to also use 4 character groups, and got similar speed. http://ideone.com/KbTFe

Comment: Would it be difficult to modify it to work with uint64_t? I moved this code to C and replaced 'T' with int type and it works, but it doesn't work for uint64_t and I don't have a clue how to customize it.

Answer (score 13):

Benchmark data for the code provided in the question:

### On ideone (gcc 4.3.4):

- stringstreams: 4.4 MB/s
- sprintf: 25.0 MB/s
- [mine (Ben Voigt)](http://ideone.com/SsEUW): 55.8 MB/s
- [Timo](http://ideone.com/VpKO3): 58.5 MB/s
- [user434507](http://ideone.com/0uhhX): 199 MB/s
- [user434507's Ben-Timo-507 hybrid](http://ideone.com/VLUco): 263 MB/s

### Core i7, Windows 7 64-bit, 8 GB RAM, Visual C++ 2010 32-bit:

`cl /Ox /EHsc`

- stringstreams: 3.39 MB/s, 3.67 MB/s
- sprintf: 16.8 MB/s, 16.2 MB/s
- mine: 194 MB/s, 207 MB/s (with PGO enabled: 250 MB/s)

### Core i7, Windows 7 64-bit, 8 GB RAM, Visual C++ 2010 64-bit:

`cl /Ox /EHsc`

- stringstreams: 4.42 MB/s, 4.92 MB/s
- sprintf: 21.0 MB/s, 20.8 MB/s
- mine: 238 MB/s, 228 MB/s

### Core i7, Windows 7 64-bit, 8 GB RAM, cygwin gcc 4.3.4:

`g++ -O3`

- stringstreams: 2.19 MB/s, 2.17 MB/s
- sprintf: 13.1 MB/s, 13.4 MB/s
- mine: 30.0 MB/s, 30.2 MB/s

**edit**: I was gonna add my own answer, but the question was was closed so I'm adding it here. :) I wrote my own algorithm and managed to get a decent improvement over Ben's code, though I only tested it in MSVC 2010. I also made a benchmark of all the implementations presented so far, using the same testing setup that was in Ben's original code. -- Timo

### Intel Q9450, Win XP 32bit, MSVC 2010

`cl /O2 /EHsc`

- stringstream: 2.87 MB/s
- sprintf: 16.1 MB/s
- Ben: 202 MB/s
- Ben (unsigned buffer): 82.0 MB/s
- ergosys (updated version): 64.2 MB/s
- user434507: 172 MB/s
- Timo: 241 MB/s

-

```
const char digit_pairs[201] = {
  "00010203040506070809"
  "10111213141516171819"
  "20212223242526272829"
  "30313233343536373839"
  "40414243444546474849"
  "50515253545556575859"
  "60616263646566676869"
  "70717273747576777879"
  "80818283848586878889"
  "90919293949596979899"
};

static const int BUFFER_SIZE = 11;

std::string itostr(int val)
{
  char buf[BUFFER_SIZE];
  char *it = &buf[BUFFER_SIZE-2];

  if(val>=0) {
    int div = val/100;
    while(div) {
      memcpy(it,&digit_pairs[2*(val-div*100)],2);
      val = div;
      it-=2;
      div = val/100;
    }
    memcpy(it,&digit_pairs[2*val],2);
    if(val<10)
      it++;
  } else {
    int div = val/100;
    while(div) {
      memcpy(it,&digit_pairs[-2*(val-div*100)],2);
      val = div;
      it-=2;
      div = val/100;
    }
    memcpy(it,&digit_pairs[-2*val],2);
    if(val<=-10)
      it--;
    *it = '-';
  }

  return std::string(it,&buf[BUFFER_SIZE]-it);
}

std::string itostr(unsigned int val)
{
  char buf[BUFFER_SIZE];
  char *it = (char*)&buf[BUFFER_SIZE-2];

  int div = val/100;
  while(div) {
    memcpy(it,&digit_pairs[2*(val-div*100)],2);
    val = div;
    it-=2;
    div = val/100;
  }
  memcpy(it,&digit_pairs[2*val],2);
  if(val<10)
    it++;

  return std::string((char*)it,(char*)&buf[BUFFER_SIZE]-(char*)it);
}
```

Comment: thanks for these infos , please explain about gcc speed ! it is very low :(

Comment: @Behrouz: Indeed.  I'm not exactly sure why gcc is so slow, whether it is gcc's version of `std::string` or poor optimization of the arithmetic code.  I shall make another version that doesn't convert to `std::string` at the end and see whether gcc fares any better.

Comment: @Timo: That's very cool.  I didn't really expect the change to an unsigned buffer to help with VC++, which was already quite fast, so it was only applicable to gcc and now user434507 has provided a far better version there.

Comment: I think you should add a version that does not convert to std::string. By changing just one line of code the function runs in half the time on my machine, using GCC. And by removing the std::string people would be able to use this function inside C programs.

Answer (score 13):

While the info we get here for the algorithms is pretty nice, I think the question is "broken", and I'll explain why I think this:

The question asks to take the performance of `int`->`std::string` conversion, and this *may* be of interest when comparing a commonly available method, such as different stringstream implementations or boost::lexical_cast. It does not, however, make sense when asking for *new code*, a specialized algorithm, to do this. The reason is that int2string will always involve heap allocation from std::string and if we are trying to squeeze the last out of our conversion algorithm, I do not think it makes sense to mix these measurements up with the heap allocations done by std::string. If I want performant conversion I will *always* use a fixed size buffer and certainly never allocate anything on the heap!

To sum up, I think the timings should be split:

- First, fastest (int -> fixed buffer) conversion.
- Second, timing of (fixed buffer -> std::string) copy.
- Third, checking how the std::string allocation can directly be used as buffer, to save the copying.

These aspects should not be mixed up in one timing, IMHO.

Comment: <quote>int2string will always involve heap allocation from std::string</quote>  Not with the small-string optimization, which is present in most current implementations of the Standard Library.

Comment: In the end, though, the "output as `std::string`" requirement was placed there just to make things fair and consistent for all submissions.  Algorithms that are faster to make `std::string` results will also be faster to fill a preallocated buffer.

Comment: @Ben - good comments. Esp. the sm.str.opt. is something I'll have to remember in the future when judging std.string performance.

Answer (score 7):

I can't test under VS, but this seems to be faster than your code for g++, about 10%.  It could probably be tuned, the 
decision values chosen are guesses. int only, sorry.

```
typedef unsigned buf_t; 

static buf_t * reduce(unsigned val, buf_t * stp) {
   unsigned above = val / 10000; 
   if (above != 0) {
      stp = reduce(above, stp); 
      val -= above * 10000; 
   }

   buf_t digit  = val / 1000; 
   *stp++ = digit + '0'; 
   val -= digit * 1000; 

   digit  = val / 100; 
   *stp++ = digit + '0'; 
   val -= digit * 100; 

   digit  = val / 10; 
   *stp++ = digit + '0'; 
   val -= digit * 10; 
   *stp++ = val + '0'; 
   return stp; 
}

std::string itostr(int input) {

   buf_t buf[16]; 


   if(input == INT_MIN) {  
      char buf2[16]; 
      std::sprintf(buf2, "%d", input); 
      return std::string(buf2); 
   }

   // handle negative
   unsigned val = input;
   if(input < 0) 
      val = -input;

   buf[0] = '0'; 
   buf_t* endp = reduce(val, buf+1); 
   *endp = 127; 

   buf_t * stp = buf+1; 
   while (*stp == '0') 
      stp++;
   if (stp == endp)
      stp--; 

   if (input < 0) { 
      stp--; 
      *stp = '-'; 
   }
   return std::string(stp, endp); 
}
```

Comment: With unsigned variant: http://ideone.com/pswq9.  It seems that changing the buffer type from `char` to `unsigned` produces a similar speed improvement in my code, at least on gcc/ideone http://ideone.com/uthKK.  I'll test on VS tomorrow.

Answer (score 7):

Updated user2985907's answer... modp_ufast...

```
Integer To String Test (Type 1)
[modp_ufast]Numbers: 240000000  Total:   657777786      Time:  1.1633sec        Rate:206308473.0686nums/sec
[sprintf] Numbers: 240000000    Total:   657777786      Time: 24.3629sec        Rate:  9851045.8556nums/sec
[karma]   Numbers: 240000000    Total:   657777786      Time:  5.2389sec        Rate: 45810870.7171nums/sec
[strtk]   Numbers: 240000000    Total:   657777786      Time:  3.3126sec        Rate: 72450283.7492nums/sec
[so   ]   Numbers: 240000000    Total:   657777786      Time:  3.0828sec        Rate: 77852152.8820nums/sec
[timo ]   Numbers: 240000000    Total:   657777786      Time:  4.7349sec        Rate: 50687912.9889nums/sec
[voigt]   Numbers: 240000000    Total:   657777786      Time:  5.1689sec        Rate: 46431985.1142nums/sec
[hopman]  Numbers: 240000000    Total:   657777786      Time:  4.6169sec        Rate: 51982554.6497nums/sec
Press any key to continue . . .

Integer To String Test(Type 2)
[modp_ufast]Numbers: 240000000  Total:   660000000      Time:  0.5072sec        Rate:473162716.4618nums/sec
[sprintf] Numbers: 240000000    Total:   660000000      Time: 22.3483sec        Rate: 10739062.9383nums/sec
[karma]   Numbers: 240000000    Total:   660000000      Time:  4.2471sec        Rate: 56509024.3035nums/sec
[strtk]   Numbers: 240000000    Total:   660000000      Time:  2.1683sec        Rate:110683636.7123nums/sec
[so   ]   Numbers: 240000000    Total:   660000000      Time:  2.7133sec        Rate: 88454602.1423nums/sec
[timo ]   Numbers: 240000000    Total:   660000000      Time:  2.8030sec        Rate: 85623453.3872nums/sec
[voigt]   Numbers: 240000000    Total:   660000000      Time:  3.4019sec        Rate: 70549286.7776nums/sec
[hopman]  Numbers: 240000000    Total:   660000000      Time:  2.7849sec        Rate: 86178023.8743nums/sec
Press any key to continue . . .

Integer To String Test (type 3)
[modp_ufast]Numbers: 240000000  Total:   505625000      Time:  1.6482sec        Rate:145610315.7819nums/sec
[sprintf] Numbers: 240000000    Total:   505625000      Time: 20.7064sec        Rate: 11590618.6109nums/sec
[karma]   Numbers: 240000000    Total:   505625000      Time:  4.3036sec        Rate: 55767734.3570nums/sec
[strtk]   Numbers: 240000000    Total:   505625000      Time:  2.9297sec        Rate: 81919227.9275nums/sec
[so   ]   Numbers: 240000000    Total:   505625000      Time:  3.0278sec        Rate: 79266003.8158nums/sec
[timo ]   Numbers: 240000000    Total:   505625000      Time:  4.0631sec        Rate: 59068204.3266nums/sec
[voigt]   Numbers: 240000000    Total:   505625000      Time:  4.5616sec        Rate: 52613393.0285nums/sec
[hopman]  Numbers: 240000000    Total:   505625000      Time:  4.1248sec        Rate: 58184194.4569nums/sec
Press any key to continue . . .

int ufast_utoa10(unsigned int value, char* str)
{
#define JOIN(N) N "0", N "1", N "2", N "3", N "4", N "5", N "6", N "7", N "8", N "9"
#define JOIN2(N) JOIN(N "0"), JOIN(N "1"), JOIN(N "2"), JOIN(N "3"), JOIN(N "4"), \
                 JOIN(N "5"), JOIN(N "6"), JOIN(N "7"), JOIN(N "8"), JOIN(N "9")
#define JOIN3(N) JOIN2(N "0"), JOIN2(N "1"), JOIN2(N "2"), JOIN2(N "3"), JOIN2(N "4"), \
                 JOIN2(N "5"), JOIN2(N "6"), JOIN2(N "7"), JOIN2(N "8"), JOIN2(N "9")
#define JOIN4    JOIN3("0"), JOIN3("1"), JOIN3("2"), JOIN3("3"), JOIN3("4"), \
                 JOIN3("5"), JOIN3("6"), JOIN3("7"), JOIN3("8"), JOIN3("9")
#define JOIN5(N) JOIN(N), JOIN(N "1"), JOIN(N "2"), JOIN(N "3"), JOIN(N "4"), \
                 JOIN(N "5"), JOIN(N "6"), JOIN(N "7"), JOIN(N "8"), JOIN(N "9")
#define JOIN6    JOIN5(), JOIN5("1"), JOIN5("2"), JOIN5("3"), JOIN5("4"), \
                 JOIN5("5"), JOIN5("6"), JOIN5("7"), JOIN5("8"), JOIN5("9")
#define F(N)     ((N) >= 100 ? 3 : (N) >= 10 ? 2 : 1)
#define F10(N)   F(N),F(N+1),F(N+2),F(N+3),F(N+4),F(N+5),F(N+6),F(N+7),F(N+8),F(N+9)
#define F100(N)  F10(N),F10(N+10),F10(N+20),F10(N+30),F10(N+40),\
                 F10(N+50),F10(N+60),F10(N+70),F10(N+80),F10(N+90)
  static const short offsets[] = { F100(0), F100(100), F100(200), F100(300), F100(400),
                                  F100(500), F100(600), F100(700), F100(800), F100(900)};
  static const char table1[][4] = { JOIN("") }; 
  static const char table2[][4] = { JOIN2("") }; 
  static const char table3[][4] = { JOIN3("") };
  static const char table4[][5] = { JOIN4 }; 
  static const char table5[][4] = { JOIN6 };
#undef JOIN
#undef JOIN2
#undef JOIN3
#undef JOIN4
  char *wstr;
  int remains[2];
  unsigned int v2;
  if (value >= 100000000) {
    v2 = value / 10000;
    remains[0] = value - v2 * 10000;
    value = v2;
    v2 = value / 10000;
    remains[1] = value - v2 * 10000;
    value = v2;
    wstr = str;
    if (value >= 1000) {
      *(__int32 *) wstr = *(__int32 *) table4[value];
      wstr += 4;
    } else {
      *(__int32 *) wstr = *(__int32 *) table5[value];
      wstr += offsets[value];
    }
    *(__int32 *) wstr = *(__int32 *) table4[remains[1]];
    wstr += 4;
    *(__int32 *) wstr = *(__int32 *) table4[remains[0]];
    wstr += 4;
    *wstr = 0;
    return (wstr - str);
  }
  else if (value >= 10000) {
    v2 = value / 10000;
    remains[0] = value - v2 * 10000;
    value = v2;
    wstr = str;
    if (value >= 1000) {
      *(__int32 *) wstr = *(__int32 *) table4[value];
      wstr += 4;
      *(__int32 *) wstr = *(__int32 *) table4[remains[0]];
      wstr += 4;
      *wstr = 0;
      return 8;
    } else {
      *(__int32 *) wstr = *(__int32 *) table5[value];
      wstr += offsets[value];
      *(__int32 *) wstr = *(__int32 *) table4[remains[0]];
      wstr += 4;
      *wstr = 0;
      return (wstr - str);
    }
  }
  else {
    if (value >= 1000) {
      *(__int32 *) str = *(__int32 *) table4[value];
      str += 4;
      *str = 0;
      return 4;
    } else if (value >= 100) {
      *(__int32 *) str = *(__int32 *) table3[value];
      return 3;
    } else if (value >= 10) {
      *(__int16 *) str = *(__int16 *) table2[value];
      str += 2;
      *str = 0;
      return 2;
    } else {
      *(__int16 *) str = *(__int16 *) table1[value];
      return 1;
    }
  }
}

int ufast_itoa10(int value, char* str) {
  if (value < 0) { *(str++) = '-'; 
    return ufast_utoa10(-value, str) + 1; 
  }
  else return ufast_utoa10(value, str);
}


    void ufast_test() {

   print_mode("[modp_ufast]");

   std::string s;
   s.reserve(32);
   std::size_t total_length = 0;
   strtk::util::timer t;
   t.start();

   char buf[128];
   int len;
   for (int i = (-max_i2s / 2); i < (max_i2s / 2); ++i)
   {
      #ifdef enable_test_type01
      s.resize(ufast_itoa10(((i & 1) ? i : -i), const_cast<char*>(s.c_str())));
      total_length += s.size();
      #endif

      #ifdef enable_test_type02
      s.resize(ufast_itoa10(max_i2s + i, const_cast<char*>(s.c_str())));
      total_length += s.size();
      #endif

      #ifdef enable_test_type03
      s.resize(ufast_itoa10(randval[(max_i2s + i) & 1023], const_cast<char*>(s.c_str())));
      total_length += s.size();
      #endif
   }
   t.stop();
   printf("Numbers:%10lu\tTotal:%12lu\tTime:%8.4fsec\tRate:%14.4fnums/sec\n",
          static_cast<unsigned long>(3 * max_i2s),
          static_cast<unsigned long>(total_length),
          t.time(),
          (3.0 * max_i2s) / t.time());
}
```

Comment: You never put it into the string. Also I don't know why your results for everyone else's code are so low, your CPU isn't slow.

Comment: modp_ufast has an error, it returns 10 instead of 1000000, 19 instead of 1090000 and etc,  till 11000000.

Comment: Modified ufast returns invalid values (stopped after a few errors).

`Mismatch found:
Generated: -99
Reference: -9099999

Mismatch found:
Generated: -99
Reference: -9099998

Mismatch found:
Generated: -99
Reference: -9099997`

Comment: There is a more portable version with benchmarks available here: https://github.com/fmtlib/format-benchmark/blob/master/src/u2985907.h

Answer (score 4):

I've had this sitting around for awhile and finally got around to posting it.

A few more methods compared to the double-word at a time *hopman_fast*. The results are for the GCC's short-string-optimized std::string as otherwise performance differences get obscured by the overhead of the copy-on-write string management code. Throughput is measured the same way as elsewhere in this topic, cycle counts are for the raw serialization parts of the code prior to copying the output buffer into a string.

```
HOPMAN_FAST - performance reference  
TM_CPP, TM_VEC - scalar and vector versions of Terje Mathisen algorithm  
WM_VEC - intrinsics implementation of Wojciech Mula's vector algorithm  
AK_BW - word-at-a-time routine with a jump table that fills a buffer in reverse  
AK_FW - forward-stepping word-at-a-time routine with a jump table in assembly  
AK_UNROLLED - generic word-at-a-time routine that uses an unrolled loop
```

[image: Throughput]

[image: Raw cost]

Compile-time switches:

-DVSTRING - enables SSO strings for older GCC setups
-DBSR1 - enables fast log10
-DRDTSC - enables cycle counters

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
#include <limits>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <x86intrin.h>

/* Uncomment to run */
// #define HOPMAN_FAST
// #define TM_CPP
// #define TM_VEC
// #define WM_VEC
// #define AK_UNROLLED
// #define AK_BW
// #define AK_FW

using namespace std;
#ifdef VSTRING
#include <ext/vstring.h>
typedef __gnu_cxx::__vstring string_type;
#else
typedef string string_type;
#endif

namespace detail {

#ifdef __GNUC__
#define ALIGN(N) __attribute__ ((aligned(N)))
#define PACK __attribute__ ((packed))
  inline size_t num_digits(unsigned u) {
    struct {
      uint32_t count;
      uint32_t max;
    } static digits[32] ALIGN(64) = {
    { 1, 9 }, { 1, 9 }, { 1, 9 }, { 1, 9 },
    { 2, 99 }, { 2, 99 }, { 2, 99 },
    { 3, 999 }, { 3, 999 }, { 3, 999 },
    { 4, 9999 }, { 4, 9999 }, { 4, 9999 }, { 4, 9999 },
    { 5, 99999 }, { 5, 99999 }, { 5, 99999 },
    { 6, 999999 }, { 6, 999999 }, { 6, 999999 },
    { 7, 9999999 }, { 7, 9999999 }, { 7, 9999999 }, { 7, 9999999 },
    { 8, 99999999 }, { 8, 99999999 }, { 8, 99999999 },
    { 9, 999999999 }, { 9, 999999999 }, { 9, 999999999 },
    { 10, UINT_MAX }, { 10, UINT_MAX }
    };
#if (defined(i386) || defined(__x86_64__)) && (defined(BSR1) || defined(BSR2))
    size_t l = u;
#if defined(BSR1)
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
      "bsrl %k0, %k0    \n\t"
      "shlq $32, %q1    \n\t" 
      "movq %c2(,%0,8), %0\n\t" 
      "cmpq %0, %q1     \n\t"
      "seta %b1         \n\t"
      "addl %1, %k0     \n\t"
      : "+r" (l), "+r"(u)
      : "i"(digits)
      : "cc"
    );
    return l;
#else
    __asm__ __volatile__ ( "bsr %0, %0;"  : "+r" (l) );
    return digits[l].count + ( u > digits[l].max );
#endif
#else
    size_t l = (u != 0) ? 31 - __builtin_clz(u) : 0;
    return digits[l].count + ( u > digits[l].max );
#endif 
  }
#else 
  inline unsigned msb_u32(unsigned x) {
    static const unsigned bval[] = { 0,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4 };
    unsigned base = 0;
    if (x & (unsigned) 0xFFFF0000) { base += 32/2; x >>= 32/2; }
    if (x & (unsigned) 0x0000FF00) { base += 32/4; x >>= 32/4; }
    if (x & (unsigned) 0x000000F0) { base += 32/8; x >>= 32/8; }
    return base + bval[x];
  }

  inline size_t num_digits(unsigned x) {
    static const unsigned powertable[] = {
  0,10,100,1000,10000,100000,1000000,10000000,100000000, 1000000000 };
    size_t lg_ten = msb_u32(x) * 1233 >> 12;
    size_t adjust = (x >= powertable[lg_ten]);
    return lg_ten + adjust;
  }
#endif /* __GNUC__ */

  struct CharBuffer {
    class reverse_iterator : public iterator<random_access_iterator_tag, char> {
        char* m_p;
      public:
        reverse_iterator(char* p) : m_p(p - 1) {}
        reverse_iterator operator++() { return --m_p; }
        reverse_iterator operator++(int) { return m_p--; }
        char operator*() const { return *m_p; }
        bool operator==( reverse_iterator it) const { return m_p == it.m_p; }
        bool operator!=( reverse_iterator it) const { return m_p != it.m_p; }
        difference_type operator-( reverse_iterator it) const { return it.m_p - m_p; }
    };
  };

  union PairTable {
    char c[2];
    unsigned short u;
  } PACK table[100] ALIGN(1024) = {
    {{'0','0'}},{{'0','1'}},{{'0','2'}},{{'0','3'}},{{'0','4'}},{{'0','5'}},{{'0','6'}},{{'0','7'}},{{'0','8'}},{{'0','9'}},
    {{'1','0'}},{{'1','1'}},{{'1','2'}},{{'1','3'}},{{'1','4'}},{{'1','5'}},{{'1','6'}},{{'1','7'}},{{'1','8'}},{{'1','9'}},
    {{'2','0'}},{{'2','1'}},{{'2','2'}},{{'2','3'}},{{'2','4'}},{{'2','5'}},{{'2','6'}},{{'2','7'}},{{'2','8'}},{{'2','9'}},
    {{'3','0'}},{{'3','1'}},{{'3','2'}},{{'3','3'}},{{'3','4'}},{{'3','5'}},{{'3','6'}},{{'3','7'}},{{'3','8'}},{{'3','9'}},
    {{'4','0'}},{{'4','1'}},{{'4','2'}},{{'4','3'}},{{'4','4'}},{{'4','5'}},{{'4','6'}},{{'4','7'}},{{'4','8'}},{{'4','9'}},
    {{'5','0'}},{{'5','1'}},{{'5','2'}},{{'5','3'}},{{'5','4'}},{{'5','5'}},{{'5','6'}},{{'5','7'}},{{'5','8'}},{{'5','9'}},
    {{'6','0'}},{{'6','1'}},{{'6','2'}},{{'6','3'}},{{'6','4'}},{{'6','5'}},{{'6','6'}},{{'6','7'}},{{'6','8'}},{{'6','9'}},
    {{'7','0'}},{{'7','1'}},{{'7','2'}},{{'7','3'}},{{'7','4'}},{{'7','5'}},{{'7','6'}},{{'7','7'}},{{'7','8'}},{{'7','9'}},
    {{'8','0'}},{{'8','1'}},{{'8','2'}},{{'8','3'}},{{'8','4'}},{{'8','5'}},{{'8','6'}},{{'8','7'}},{{'8','8'}},{{'8','9'}},
    {{'9','0'}},{{'9','1'}},{{'9','2'}},{{'9','3'}},{{'9','4'}},{{'9','5'}},{{'9','6'}},{{'9','7'}},{{'9','8'}},{{'9','9'}}
  };
} // namespace detail

struct progress_timer {
    clock_t c;
    progress_timer() : c(clock()) {}
    int elapsed() { return clock() - c; }
    ~progress_timer() {
        clock_t d = clock() - c;
        cout << d / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << "."
            << (((d * 1000) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) % 1000 / 100)
            << (((d * 1000) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) % 100 / 10)
            << (((d * 1000) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) % 10)
            << " s" << endl;
    }
};

#ifdef HOPMAN_FAST
namespace hopman_fast {

    static unsigned long cpu_cycles = 0;

    struct itostr_helper {
        static ALIGN(1024) unsigned out[10000];

        itostr_helper() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                unsigned v = i;
                char * o = (char*)(out + i);
                o[3] = v % 10 + '0';
                o[2] = (v % 100) / 10 + '0';
                o[1] = (v % 1000) / 100 + '0';
                o[0] = (v % 10000) / 1000;
                if (o[0]) o[0] |= 0x30;
                else if (o[1] != '0') o[0] |= 0x20;
                else if (o[2] != '0') o[0] |= 0x10;
                else o[0] |= 0x00;
            }
        }
    };
    unsigned itostr_helper::out[10000];

    itostr_helper hlp_init;

    template <typename T>
    string_type itostr(T o) {
        typedef itostr_helper hlp;
#ifdef RDTSC
        long first_clock = __rdtsc();
#endif
        unsigned blocks[3], *b = blocks + 2;
        blocks[0] = o < 0 ? ~o + 1 : o;
        blocks[2] = blocks[0] % 10000; blocks[0] /= 10000;
        blocks[2] = hlp::out[blocks[2]];

        if (blocks[0]) {
            blocks[1] = blocks[0] % 10000; blocks[0] /= 10000;
            blocks[1] = hlp::out[blocks[1]];
            blocks[2] |= 0x30303030;
            b--;
        }

        if (blocks[0]) {
            blocks[0] = hlp::out[blocks[0] % 10000];
            blocks[1] |= 0x30303030;
            b--;
        }

        char* f = ((char*)b);
        f += 3 - (*f >> 4);

        char* str = (char*)blocks;
        if (o < 0) *--f = '-';

        str += 12;
#ifdef RDTSC
        cpu_cycles += __rdtsc() - first_clock;
#endif
        return string_type(f, str);
    }
      unsigned long cycles() { return cpu_cycles; }
      void reset() { cpu_cycles = 0; }
}
#endif

namespace ak {
#ifdef AK_UNROLLED
  namespace unrolled {
    static unsigned long cpu_cycles = 0;

    template <typename value_type> class Proxy {
      static const size_t MaxValueSize = 16;

      static inline char* generate(int value, char* buffer) {
        union { char* pc; unsigned short* pu; } b = { buffer + MaxValueSize };
        unsigned u, v = value < 0 ? unsigned(~value) + 1 : value;
        *--b.pu = detail::table[v % 100].u; u = v;
        if ((v /= 100)) {
          *--b.pu = detail::table[v % 100].u; u = v;
          if ((v /= 100)) {
            *--b.pu = detail::table[v % 100].u; u = v;
            if ((v /= 100)) {
              *--b.pu = detail::table[v % 100].u; u = v;
              if ((v /= 100)) {
                *--b.pu = detail::table[v % 100].u; u = v;
        } } } }
        *(b.pc -= (u >= 10)) = '-';
        return b.pc + (value >= 0);
      }
      static inline char* generate(unsigned value, char* buffer) {
        union { char* pc; unsigned short* pu; } b = { buffer + MaxValueSize };
        unsigned u, v = value;
        *--b.pu = detail::table[v % 100].u; u = v;
        if ((v /= 100)) {
          *--b.pu = detail::table[v % 100].u; u = v;
          if ((v /= 100)) {
            *--b.pu = detail::table[v % 100].u; u = v;
            if ((v /= 100)) {
              *--b.pu = detail::table[v % 100].u; u = v;
              if ((v /= 100)) {
                *--b.pu = detail::table[v % 100].u; u = v;
        } } } }
        return b.pc + (u < 10);
      }
    public:
      static inline string_type convert(value_type v) {
        char buf[MaxValueSize];
#ifdef RDTSC
        long first_clock = __rdtsc();
#endif
        char* p = generate(v, buf);
        char* e = buf + MaxValueSize;
#ifdef RDTSC
        cpu_cycles += __rdtsc() - first_clock;
#endif
        return string_type(p, e);
      }
    };
    string_type itostr(int i) { return Proxy<int>::convert(i); }
    string_type itostr(unsigned i) { return Proxy<unsigned>::convert(i); }
    unsigned long cycles() { return cpu_cycles; }
    void reset() { cpu_cycles = 0; }
  }
#endif

#if defined(AK_BW)
  namespace bw {
    static unsigned long cpu_cycles = 0;
    typedef uint64_t u_type;

    template <typename value_type> class Proxy {

      static inline void generate(unsigned v, size_t len, char* buffer) {
        u_type u = v;
        switch(len) {
        default: u = (v * 1374389535ULL) >> 37; *(uint16_t*)(buffer + 8) = detail::table[v -= 100 * u].u; 
        case  8: v = (u * 1374389535ULL) >> 37; *(uint16_t*)(buffer + 6) = detail::table[u -= 100 * v].u; 
        case  6: u = (v * 1374389535ULL) >> 37; *(uint16_t*)(buffer + 4) = detail::table[v -= 100 * u].u;
        case  4: v = (u * 167773) >> 24; *(uint16_t*)(buffer + 2) = detail::table[u -= 100 * v].u;
        case  2: *(uint16_t*)buffer = detail::table[v].u;
        case  0: return;
        case  9: u = (v * 1374389535ULL) >> 37; *(uint16_t*)(buffer + 7) = detail::table[v -= 100 * u].u;
        case  7: v = (u * 1374389535ULL) >> 37; *(uint16_t*)(buffer + 5) = detail::table[u -= 100 * v].u;
        case  5: u = (v * 1374389535ULL) >> 37; *(uint16_t*)(buffer + 3) = detail::table[v -= 100 * u].u;
        case  3: v = (u * 167773) >> 24; *(uint16_t*)(buffer + 1) = detail::table[u -= 100 * v].u;
        case  1: *buffer = v + 0x30;
        }
      }
    public:
      static inline string_type convert(bool neg, unsigned val) {
        char buf[16];
#ifdef RDTSC
        long first_clock = __rdtsc();
#endif
        size_t len = detail::num_digits(val);
        buf[0] = '-';

        char* e = buf + neg;
        generate(val, len, e);
        e += len;
#ifdef RDTSC
        cpu_cycles += __rdtsc() - first_clock;
#endif
        return string_type(buf, e);
      }
    };
    string_type itostr(int i) { return Proxy<int>::convert(i < 0, i < 0 ? unsigned(~i) + 1 : i); }
    string_type itostr(unsigned i) { return Proxy<unsigned>::convert(false, i); }
    unsigned long cycles() { return cpu_cycles; }
    void reset() { cpu_cycles = 0; }
  }
#endif

#if defined(AK_FW)
  namespace fw {
        static unsigned long cpu_cycles = 0;
        typedef uint32_t u_type;
        template <typename value_type> class Proxy {

        static inline void generate(unsigned v, size_t len, char* buffer) {
#if defined(__GNUC__) && defined(__x86_64__)
          uint16_t w;
          uint32_t u;
          __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "jmp %*T%=(,%3,8)       \n\t"
        "T%=: .quad L0%=        \n\t"
        "     .quad L1%=        \n\t"
        "     .quad L2%=        \n\t"
        "     .quad L3%=        \n\t"
        "     .quad L4%=        \n\t"
        "     .quad L5%=        \n\t"
        "     .quad L6%=        \n\t"
        "     .quad L7%=        \n\t"
        "     .quad L8%=        \n\t"
        "     .quad L9%=        \n\t"
        "     .quad L10%=       \n\t"
        "L10%=:         \n\t"
        " imulq $1441151881, %q0, %q1\n\t"
        " shrq $57, %q1     \n\t"
        " movw %c5(,%q1,2), %w2 \n\t"
        " imull $100000000, %1, %1  \n\t"
        " subl %1, %0       \n\t"
        " movw %w2, (%4)        \n\t"
        "L8%=:          \n\t"
        " imulq $1125899907, %q0, %q1\n\t"
        " shrq $50, %q1     \n\t"
        " movw %c5(,%q1,2), %w2 \n\t"
        " imull $1000000, %1, %1    \n\t"
        " subl %1, %0       \n\t"
        " movw %w2, -8(%4,%3)   \n\t"
        "L6%=:          \n\t"
        " imulq $429497, %q0, %q1   \n\t"
        " shrq $32, %q1     \n\t"
        " movw %c5(,%q1,2), %w2 \n\t"
        " imull $10000, %1, %1  \n\t"
        " subl %1, %0       \n\t"
        " movw %w2, -6(%4,%3)   \n\t"
        "L4%=:          \n\t"
        " imull $167773, %0, %1 \n\t"
        " shrl $24, %1      \n\t"
        " movw %c5(,%q1,2), %w2 \n\t"
        " imull $100, %1, %1    \n\t"
        " subl %1, %0       \n\t"
        " movw %w2, -4(%4,%3)   \n\t"
        "L2%=:          \n\t"
        " movw %c5(,%q0,2), %w2 \n\t"
        " movw %w2, -2(%4,%3)   \n\t"
        "L0%=: jmp 1f       \n\t"
        "L9%=:          \n\t"
        " imulq $1801439851, %q0, %q1\n\t"
        " shrq $54, %q1     \n\t"
        " movw %c5(,%q1,2), %w2 \n\t"
        " imull $10000000, %1, %1   \n\t"
        " subl %1, %0       \n\t"
        " movw %w2, (%4)        \n\t"
        "L7%=:          \n\t"
        " imulq $43980466, %q0, %q1 \n\t"
        " shrq $42, %q1     \n\t"
        " movw %c5(,%q1,2), %w2 \n\t"
        " imull $100000, %1, %1 \n\t"
        " subl %1, %0       \n\t"
        " movw %w2, -7(%4,%3)   \n\t"
        "L5%=:          \n\t"
        " imulq $268436, %q0, %q1   \n\t"
        " shrq $28, %q1     \n\t"
        " movw %c5(,%q1,2), %w2 \n\t"
        " imull $1000, %1, %1   \n\t"
        " subl %1, %0       \n\t"
        " movw %w2, -5(%4,%3)   \n\t"
        "L3%=:          \n\t"
        " imull $6554, %0, %1   \n\t"
        " shrl $15, %1      \n\t"
        " andb $254, %b1        \n\t"
        " movw %c5(,%q1), %w2   \n\t"
        " leal (%1,%1,4), %1    \n\t"
        " subl %1, %0       \n\t"
        " movw %w2, -3(%4,%3)   \n\t"
        "L1%=:          \n\t"
        " addl $48, %0      \n\t"
        " movb %b0, -1(%4,%3)   \n\t"
        "1:             \n\t"
        : "+r"(v), "=&q"(u), "=&r"(w)
        : "r"(len), "r"(buffer), "i"(detail::table)
        : "memory", "cc"
          ); 
#else
          u_type u;
          switch(len) {
        default: u = (v * 1441151881ULL) >> 57; *(uint16_t*)(buffer) = detail::table[u].u; v -= u * 100000000;
        case  8: u = (v * 1125899907ULL) >> 50; *(uint16_t*)(buffer + len - 8) = detail::table[u].u; v -= u * 1000000;
        case  6: u = (v * 429497ULL) >> 32; *(uint16_t*)(buffer + len - 6) = detail::table[u].u; v -= u * 10000;
        case  4: u = (v * 167773) >> 24; *(uint16_t*)(buffer + len - 4) = detail::table[u].u; v -= u * 100;
        case  2: *(uint16_t*)(buffer + len - 2) = detail::table[v].u;
        case  0: return;
        case  9: u = (v * 1801439851ULL) >> 54; *(uint16_t*)(buffer) = detail::table[u].u; v -= u * 10000000; 
        case  7: u = (v * 43980466ULL) >> 42; *(uint16_t*)(buffer + len - 7) = detail::table[u].u; v -= u * 100000; 
        case  5: u = (v * 268436ULL) >> 28;  *(uint16_t*)(buffer + len - 5) = detail::table[u].u; v -= u * 1000;
        case  3: u = (v * 6554) >> 16; *(uint16_t*)(buffer + len - 3) = detail::table[u].u; v -= u * 10;
        case  1: *(buffer + len - 1) = v + 0x30;
          }
#endif
        }
      public:
        static inline string_type convert(bool neg, unsigned val) {
        char buf[16];
#ifdef RDTSC
        long first_clock = __rdtsc();
#endif
        size_t len = detail::num_digits(val);
        if (neg) buf[0] = '-';
        char* e = buf + len + neg;
        generate(val, len, buf + neg);
#ifdef RDTSC
        cpu_cycles += __rdtsc() - first_clock;
#endif
        return string_type(buf, e);
        }
      };
      string_type itostr(int i) { return Proxy<int>::convert(i < 0, i < 0 ? unsigned(~i) + 1 : i); }
      string_type itostr(unsigned i) { return Proxy<unsigned>::convert(false, i); }
      unsigned long cycles() { return cpu_cycles; }
      void reset() { cpu_cycles = 0; }
  }
#endif
} // ak

namespace wm {
#ifdef WM_VEC
#if defined(__GNUC__) && defined(__x86_64__)
  namespace vec {
      static unsigned long cpu_cycles = 0;

      template <typename value_type> class Proxy {

      static inline unsigned generate(unsigned v, char* buf) {
        static struct {
          unsigned short mul_10[8];
          unsigned short div_const[8];
          unsigned short shl_const[8];
          unsigned char  to_ascii[16];
        } ALIGN(64) bits = 
        {
          { // mul_10
           10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10
          },
          { // div_const
            8389, 5243, 13108, 0x8000, 8389, 5243, 13108, 0x8000
          },
          { // shl_const
            1 << (16 - (23 + 2 - 16)),
            1 << (16 - (19 + 2 - 16)),
            1 << (16 - 1 - 2),
            1 << (15),
            1 << (16 - (23 + 2 - 16)),
            1 << (16 - (19 + 2 - 16)),
            1 << (16 - 1 - 2),
            1 << (15)
          },
          { // to_ascii 
            '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
            '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'
          }
        };
        unsigned x, y, l;
        x = (v * 1374389535ULL) >> 37;
        y = v;
        l = 0;
        if (x) {
          unsigned div = 0xd1b71759;
          unsigned mul = 55536;
          __m128i z, m, a, o;
          y -= 100 * x;
          z = _mm_cvtsi32_si128(x);
          m = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)bits.mul_10);
          o = _mm_mul_epu32( z, _mm_cvtsi32_si128(div));
          z = _mm_add_epi32( z, _mm_mul_epu32( _mm_cvtsi32_si128(mul), _mm_srli_epi64( o, 45) ) );
          z = _mm_slli_epi64( _mm_shuffle_epi32( _mm_unpacklo_epi16(z, z), 5 ), 2 );
          a = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)bits.to_ascii);
          z = _mm_mulhi_epu16( _mm_mulhi_epu16( z, *(__m128i*)bits.div_const ), *(__m128i*)bits.shl_const );
          z = _mm_sub_epi16( z, _mm_slli_epi64( _mm_mullo_epi16( m, z ), 16 ) );
          z = _mm_add_epi8( _mm_packus_epi16( z, _mm_xor_si128(o, o) ), a );
          x = __builtin_ctz( ~_mm_movemask_epi8( _mm_cmpeq_epi8( a, z ) ) );
          l = 8 - x;
          uint64_t q = _mm_cvtsi128_si64(z) >> (x * 8);
          *(uint64_t*)buf = q;
          buf += l;
          x = 1;
        }
        v = (y * 6554) >> 16;
        l += 1 + (x | (v != 0));
            *(unsigned short*)buf = 0x30 + ((l > 1) ? ((0x30 + y - v * 10) << 8) + v : y);
            return l;
        }
      public:
        static inline string_type convert(bool neg, unsigned val) {
        char buf[16];
#ifdef RDTSC
        long first_clock = __rdtsc();
#endif
        buf[0] = '-';
        unsigned len = generate(val, buf + neg);
        char* e = buf + len + neg;
#ifdef RDTSC
        cpu_cycles += __rdtsc() - first_clock;
#endif
        return string_type(buf, e);
        }
      };
      inline string_type itostr(int i) { return Proxy<int>::convert(i < 0, i < 0 ? unsigned(~i) + 1 : i); }
      inline string_type itostr(unsigned i) { return Proxy<unsigned>::convert(false, i); }
      unsigned long cycles() { return cpu_cycles; }
      void reset() { cpu_cycles = 0; }
  }
#endif
#endif
} // wm

namespace tmn {

#ifdef TM_CPP
  namespace cpp {
      static unsigned long cpu_cycles = 0;

      template <typename value_type> class Proxy {

        static inline void generate(unsigned v, char* buffer) {
          unsigned const f1_10000 = (1 << 28) / 10000;
          unsigned tmplo, tmphi;

          unsigned lo = v % 100000;
          unsigned hi = v / 100000;

          tmplo = lo * (f1_10000 + 1) - (lo >> 2);
          tmphi = hi * (f1_10000 + 1) - (hi >> 2);

          unsigned mask = 0x0fffffff;
          unsigned shift = 28;

          for(size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
          {
            buffer[i + 0] = '0' + (char)(tmphi >> shift);
            buffer[i + 5] = '0' + (char)(tmplo >> shift);
            tmphi = (tmphi & mask) * 5;
            tmplo = (tmplo & mask) * 5;
            mask >>= 1;
            shift--;
          }
        }
      public:
        static inline string_type convert(bool neg, unsigned val) {
#ifdef RDTSC
        long first_clock = __rdtsc();
#endif
        char buf[16];
        size_t len = detail::num_digits(val);
        char* e = buf + 11;
        generate(val, buf + 1);
        buf[10 - len] = '-';
        len += neg;
        char* b = e - len;
#ifdef RDTSC
        cpu_cycles += __rdtsc() - first_clock;
#endif
        return string_type(b, e);
        }
      };
      string_type itostr(int i) { return Proxy<int>::convert(i < 0, i < 0 ? unsigned(~i) + 1 : i); }
      string_type itostr(unsigned i) { return Proxy<unsigned>::convert(false, i); }
      unsigned long cycles() { return cpu_cycles; }
      void reset() { cpu_cycles = 0; }
  }
#endif

#ifdef TM_VEC
  namespace vec {
      static unsigned long cpu_cycles = 0;

      template <typename value_type> class Proxy {

        static inline unsigned generate(unsigned val, char* buffer) {
        static struct {
            unsigned char mul_10[16];
            unsigned char to_ascii[16];
            unsigned char gather[16];
            unsigned char shift[16];
        } ALIGN(64) bits = {
            { 10,0,0,0,10,0,0,0,10,0,0,0,10,0,0,0 },
            { '0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0' },
            { 3,5,6,7,9,10,11,13,14,15,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
            { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 }
        };

        unsigned u = val / 1000000;
        unsigned l = val - u * 1000000;

        __m128i x, h, f, m, n;

        n = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)bits.mul_10);
        x = _mm_set_epi64x( l, u );
        h = _mm_mul_epu32( x, _mm_set1_epi32(4294968) );
        x = _mm_sub_epi64( x, _mm_srli_epi64( _mm_mullo_epi32( h, _mm_set1_epi32(1000) ), 32 ) );
        f = _mm_set1_epi32((1 << 28) / 1000 + 1);
        m = _mm_srli_epi32( _mm_cmpeq_epi32(m, m), 4 );
        x = _mm_shuffle_epi32( _mm_blend_epi16( x, h, 204 ), 177 );
        f = _mm_sub_epi32( _mm_mullo_epi32(f, x), _mm_srli_epi32(x, 2) );

        h = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)bits.to_ascii);

        x = _mm_srli_epi32(f, 28);
        f = _mm_mullo_epi32( _mm_and_si128( f, m ), n );

        x = _mm_or_si128( x, _mm_slli_epi32(_mm_srli_epi32(f, 28), 8) );
        f = _mm_mullo_epi32( _mm_and_si128( f, m ), n );

        x = _mm_or_si128( x, _mm_slli_epi32(_mm_srli_epi32(f, 28), 16) );
        f = _mm_mullo_epi32( _mm_and_si128( f, m ), n );

        x = _mm_or_si128( x, _mm_slli_epi32(_mm_srli_epi32(f, 28), 24) );

        x = _mm_add_epi8( _mm_shuffle_epi8(x, *(__m128i*)bits.gather), h );
        l = __builtin_ctz( ~_mm_movemask_epi8( _mm_cmpeq_epi8( h, x ) ) | (1 << 9) );

        x = _mm_shuffle_epi8( x, _mm_add_epi8(*(__m128i*)bits.shift, _mm_set1_epi8(l) ) );

        _mm_store_si128( (__m128i*)buffer, x );
        return 10 - l;
        }

      public:
        static inline string_type convert(bool neg, unsigned val) {
#ifdef RDTSC
        long first_clock = __rdtsc();
#endif
        char arena[32];
        char* buf = (char*)((uintptr_t)(arena + 16) & ~(uintptr_t)0xf);
        *(buf - 1)= '-';
        unsigned len = generate(val, buf) + neg;
        buf -= neg;
        char* end = buf + len;
#ifdef RDTSC
        cpu_cycles += __rdtsc() - first_clock;
#endif
        return string_type(buf, end);
        }
      };
      string_type itostr(int i) { return Proxy<int>::convert(i < 0, i < 0 ? unsigned(~i) + 1 : i); }
      string_type itostr(unsigned i) { return Proxy<unsigned>::convert(false, i); }
      unsigned long cycles() { return cpu_cycles; }
      void reset() { cpu_cycles = 0; }
  }
#endif
}

bool fail(string in, string_type out) {
    cout << "failure: " << in << " => " << out << endl;
    return false;
}

#define TEST(x, n) \
    stringstream ss; \
    string_type s = n::itostr(x); \
    ss << (long long)x; \
    if (::strcmp(ss.str().c_str(), s.c_str())) { \
        passed = fail(ss.str(), s); \
        break; \
    }

#define test(x) { \
    passed = true; \
    if (0 && passed) { \
        char c = CHAR_MIN; \
        do { \
            TEST(c, x); \
        } while (c++ != CHAR_MAX); \
        if (!passed) cout << #x << " failed char!!!" << endl; \
    } \
    if (0 && passed) { \
        short c = numeric_limits<short>::min(); \
        do { \
            TEST(c, x); \
        } while (c++ != numeric_limits<short>::max()); \
        if (!passed) cout << #x << " failed short!!!" << endl; \
    } \
    if (passed) { \
        int c = numeric_limits<int>::min(); \
        do { \
            TEST(c, x); \
        } while ((c += 100000) < numeric_limits<int>::max() - 100000); \
        if (!passed) cout << #x << " failed int!!!" << endl; \
    } \
    if (passed) { \
        unsigned c = numeric_limits<unsigned>::max(); \
        do { \
            TEST(c, x); \
        } while ((c -= 100000) > 100000); \
        if (!passed) cout << #x << " failed unsigned int!!!" << endl; \
    } \
}

#define time(x, N) \
if (passed) { \
    static const int64_t limits[] = \
        {0, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, \
         1000000, 10000000, 100000000, 1000000000, 10000000000ULL }; \
    long passes = 0; \
    cout << #x << ": "; \
    progress_timer t; \
    uint64_t s = 0; \
    if (do_time) { \
        for (int n = 0; n < N1; n++) { \
            int i = 0; \
            while (i < N2) { \
                int v = ((NM - i) % limits[N]) | (limits[N] / 10); \
                int w = x::itostr(v).size() + \
                    x::itostr(-v).size(); \
                i += w * mult; \
                                passes++; \
            } \
            s += i / mult; \
        } \
    } \
    k += s; \
    cout << N << " digits: " \
          << s / double(t.elapsed()) * CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000000 << " MB/sec, " << (x::cycles() / passes >> 1) << " clocks per pass "; \
    x::reset(); \
}

#define series(n) \
    { if (do_test) test(n);    if (do_time) time(n, 1); if (do_time) time(n, 2); \
      if (do_time) time(n, 3); if (do_time) time(n, 4); if (do_time) time(n, 5); \
      if (do_time) time(n, 6); if (do_time) time(n, 7); if (do_time) time(n, 8); \
      if (do_time) time(n, 9); if (do_time) time(n, 10); }

int N1 = 1, N2 = 500000000, NM = INT_MAX;
int mult = 1; //  used to stay under timelimit on ideone
unsigned long long k = 0;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    bool do_time = 1, do_test = 1;
    bool passed = true;
#ifdef HOPMAN_FAST
    series(hopman_fast)
#endif
#ifdef WM_VEC
    series(wm::vec)
#endif
#ifdef TM_CPP
    series(tmn::cpp)
#endif
#ifdef TM_VEC
    series(tmn::vec)
#endif
#ifdef AK_UNROLLED
    series(ak::unrolled)
#endif
#if defined(AK_BW)
    series(ak::bw)
#endif
#if defined(AK_FW)
    series(ak::fw)
#endif
    return k;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe I have created the fastest integer-to-string algorithm. It's a variation of the Modulo 100 algorithm that is about 33% faster, and most importantly it's faster for both smaller and large numbers. It's called the Script ItoS Algorithm. To read the paper that explains how I engineered the algorithm @see https://github.com/kabuki-starship/kabuki-toolkit/wiki/Engineering-a-Faster-Integer-to-String-Algorithm. You may use the algorithm but please think about contributing back to the [Kabuki VM](https://github.com/kabuki-starship/kabuki-toolkit) and check out [Script](https://github.com/kabuki-starship/script/wiki/SCRIPT-Specification-RFC); especially if you're interested in AMIL-NLP and/or software-defined networking protocols.

[image]

```
/** Kabuki Toolkit
    @version 0.x
    @file    ~/source/crabs/print_itos.cc
    @author  Cale McCollough <cale.mccollough@gmail.com>
    @license Copyright (C) 2017-2018 Cale McCollough <calemccollough@gmail.com>;
             All right reserved (R). Licensed under the Apache License, Version 
             2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in 
             compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License 
             [here](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0). Unless 
             required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software 
             distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, 
             WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or 
             implied. See the License for the specific language governing 
             permissions and limitations under the License.
*/

#include <stdafx.h>
#include "print_itos.h"

#if MAJOR_SEAM >= 1 && MINOR_SEAM >= 1

#if MAJOR_SEAM == 1 && MINOR_SEAM == 1
#define DEBUG 1

#define PRINTF(format, ...) printf(format, __VA_ARGS__);
#define PUTCHAR(c) putchar(c);
#define PRINT_PRINTED\
    sprintf_s (buffer, 24, "%u", value); *text_end = 0;\
    printf ("\n    Printed \"%s\" leaving value:\"%s\":%u",\
            begin, buffer, (uint)strlen (buffer));
#define PRINT_BINARY PrintBinary (value);
#define PRINT_BINARY_TABLE PrintBinaryTable (value);
#else
#define PRINTF(x, ...)
#define PUTCHAR(c)
#define PRINT_PRINTED
#define PRINT_BINARY
#define PRINT_BINARY_TABLE
#endif

namespace _ {

void PrintLine (char c) {
    std::cout << '\n';
    for (int i = 80; i > 0; --i) 
        std::cout << c;
}

char* Print (uint32_t value, char* text, char* text_end) {

    // Lookup table for powers of 10.
    static const uint32_t k10ToThe[]{
        1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000, 100000000,
        1000000000, ~(uint32_t)0 };

    /** Lookup table of ASCII char pairs for 00, 01, ..., 99.
        To convert this algorithm to big-endian, flip the digit pair bytes. */
    static const uint16_t kDigits00To99[100] = {
        0x3030, 0x3130, 0x3230, 0x3330, 0x3430, 0x3530, 0x3630, 0x3730, 0x3830,
        0x3930, 0x3031, 0x3131, 0x3231, 0x3331, 0x3431, 0x3531, 0x3631, 0x3731,
        0x3831, 0x3931, 0x3032, 0x3132, 0x3232, 0x3332, 0x3432, 0x3532, 0x3632,
        0x3732, 0x3832, 0x3932, 0x3033, 0x3133, 0x3233, 0x3333, 0x3433, 0x3533,
        0x3633, 0x3733, 0x3833, 0x3933, 0x3034, 0x3134, 0x3234, 0x3334, 0x3434,
        0x3534, 0x3634, 0x3734, 0x3834, 0x3934, 0x3035, 0x3135, 0x3235, 0x3335,
        0x3435, 0x3535, 0x3635, 0x3735, 0x3835, 0x3935, 0x3036, 0x3136, 0x3236,
        0x3336, 0x3436, 0x3536, 0x3636, 0x3736, 0x3836, 0x3936, 0x3037, 0x3137,
        0x3237, 0x3337, 0x3437, 0x3537, 0x3637, 0x3737, 0x3837, 0x3937, 0x3038,
        0x3138, 0x3238, 0x3338, 0x3438, 0x3538, 0x3638, 0x3738, 0x3838, 0x3938,
        0x3039, 0x3139, 0x3239, 0x3339, 0x3439, 0x3539, 0x3639, 0x3739, 0x3839,
        0x3939, };

    static const char kMsbShift[] = { 4, 7, 11, 14, 17, 21, 24, 27, 30, };

    if (!text) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    if (text >= text_end) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    uint16_t* text16;
    char      digit;
    uint32_t  scalar;
    uint16_t  digits1and2,
              digits3and4,
              digits5and6,
              digits7and8;
    uint32_t  comparator;

    #if MAJOR_SEAM == 1 && MINOR_SEAM == 1
    // Write a bunches of xxxxxx to the buffer for debug purposes.
    for (int i = 0; i <= 21; ++i) {
        *(text + i) = 'x';
    }
    *(text + 21) = 0;
    char* begin = text;
    char buffer[256];
    #endif

    if (value < 10) {
        PRINTF ("\n    Range:[0, 9] length:1 ")
        if (text + 1 >= text_end) {
            return nullptr;
        }
        *text++ = '0' + (char)value;
        PRINT_PRINTED
        return text;
    }
    if (value < 100) {
        PRINTF ("\n    Range:[10, 99] length:2 ")
        if (text + 2 >= text_end) {
            return nullptr;
        }
        *reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*> (text) = kDigits00To99[value];
        PRINT_PRINTED
        return text + 2;
    }
    if (value >> 14) {
        if (value >> 27) {
            if (value >> 30) {
                PRINTF ("\n    Range:[1073741824, 4294967295] length:10")
                Print10:
                if (text + 10 >= text_end) {
                    return nullptr;
                }
                comparator = 100000000;
                digits1and2 = (uint16_t)(value / comparator);
                PRINTF ("\n    digits1and2:%u", digits1and2)
                value -= digits1and2 * comparator;
                *reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*> (text) = kDigits00To99[digits1and2];
                PRINT_PRINTED
                text += 2;
                goto Print8;
            }
            else {
                comparator = 1000000000;
                if (value >= comparator) {
                    PRINTF ("\n    Range:[100000000, 1073741823] length:10")
                    goto Print10;
                }
                PRINTF ("\n    Range:[134217727, 999999999] length:9")
                if (text + 9 >= text_end) {
                    return nullptr;
                }
                comparator = 100000000;
                digit = (char)(value / comparator);
                *text++ = digit + '0';
                PRINT_PRINTED
                value -= comparator * digit;
                goto Print8;
            }
        }
        else if (value >> 24) {
            comparator = k10ToThe[8];
            if (value >= comparator) {
                PRINTF ("\n    Range:[100000000, 134217728] length:9")
                if (text + 9 >= text_end) {
                    return nullptr;
                }
                *text++ = '1';
                PRINT_PRINTED
                value -= comparator;
            }
            PRINTF ("\n    Range:[16777216, 9999999] length:8")
            if (text + 8 >= text_end) {
                return nullptr;
            }
            Print8:
            PRINTF ("\n    Print8:")
            scalar = 10000;
            digits5and6 = (uint16_t)(value / scalar);
            digits1and2 = value - scalar * digits5and6;
            digits7and8 = digits5and6 / 100;
            digits3and4 = digits1and2 / 100;
            digits5and6 -= 100 * digits7and8;
            digits1and2 -= 100 * digits3and4;
            *reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*> (text + 6) = 
                kDigits00To99[digits1and2];
            PRINT_PRINTED
            *reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*> (text + 4) = 
                kDigits00To99[digits3and4];
            PRINT_PRINTED
            *reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*> (text + 2) = 
                kDigits00To99[digits5and6];
            PRINT_PRINTED
            *reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*> (text) = 
                kDigits00To99[digits7and8];
            PRINT_PRINTED
            return text + 8;
        }
        else if (value >> 20) {
            comparator = 10000000;
            if (value >= comparator) {
                PRINTF ("\n    Range:[10000000, 16777215] length:8")
                if (text + 8 >= text_end) {
                    return nullptr;
                }
                *text++ = '1';
                PRINT_PRINTED
                value -= comparator;
            }
            else {
                PRINTF ("\n    Range:[1048576, 9999999] length:7")
                if (text + 7 >= text_end) {
                    return nullptr;
                }
            }
            scalar = 10000;
            digits5and6 = (uint16_t)(value / scalar);
            digits1and2 = value - scalar * digits5and6;
            digits7and8 = digits5and6 / 100;
            digits3and4 = digits1and2 / 100;
            digits5and6 -= 100 * digits7and8;
            digits1and2 -= 100 * digits3and4;;
            *reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*> (text + 5) = 
                kDigits00To99[digits1and2];
            PRINT_PRINTED
            *reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*> (text + 3) = 
                kDigits00To99[digits3and4];
            PRINT_PRINTED
            *reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*> (text + 1) = 
                kDigits00To99[digits5and6];
            PRINT_PRINTED
            *text = (char)digits7and8 + '0';
            return text + 7;
        }
        else if (value >> 17) {
            comparator = 1000000;
            if (value >= comparator) {
                PRINTF ("\n    Range:[100000, 1048575] length:7")
                if (text + 7 >= text_end) {
                    return nullptr;
                }
                *text++ = '1';
                PRINT_PRINTED
                value -= comparator;
            }
            else {
                PRINTF ("\n    Range:[131072, 999999] length:6")
                if (text + 6 >= text_end) {
                    return nullptr;
                }
            }
            Print6:
            scalar = 10000;
            digits5and6 = (uint16_t)(value / scalar);
            digits1and2 = value - scalar * digits5and6;
            digits7and8 = digits5and6 / 100;
            digits3and4 = digits1and2 / 100;
            digits5and6 -= 100 * digits7and8;
            digits1and2 -= 100 * digits3and4;
            text16 = reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*> (text + 6);
            *reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*> (text + 4) = kDigits00To99[digits1and2];
            PRINT_PRINTED
            *reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*> (text + 2) = kDigits00To99[digits3and4];
            PRINT_PRINTED
            *reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*> (text    ) = kDigits00To99[digits5and6];
            PRINT_PRINTED
            return text + 6;
        }
        else { // (value >> 14)
            if (value >= 100000) {
                PRINTF ("\n    Range:[65536, 131071] length:6")
                goto Print6;
            }
            PRINTF ("\n    Range:[10000, 65535] length:5")
            if (text + 5 >= text_end) {
                return nullptr;
            }
            digits5and6 = 10000;
            digit = (uint8_t)(value / digits5and6);
            value -= digits5and6 * digit;
            *text = digit + '0';
            PRINT_PRINTED
            digits1and2 = (uint16_t)value;
            digits5and6 = 100;
            digits3and4 = digits1and2 / digits5and6;
            digits1and2 -= digits3and4 * digits5and6;
            *reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*> (text + 1) = 
                kDigits00To99[digits3and4];
            PRINT_PRINTED
                PRINTF ("\n    digits1and2:%u", digits1and2)
            *reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*> (text + 3) = 
                kDigits00To99[digits1and2];
            PRINT_PRINTED
            return text + 5;
        }
    }
    digits1and2 = (uint16_t)value;
    if (value >> 10) {
        digits5and6 = 10000;
        if (digits1and2 >= digits5and6) {
            if (text + 5 >= text_end) {
                return nullptr;
            }
            PRINTF ("\n    Range:[10000, 16383] length:5")
            *text++ = '1';
            PRINT_PRINTED
            digits1and2 -= digits5and6;

        }
        else {
            PRINTF ("\n    Range:[1024, 9999] length:4")
            if (text + 4 >= text_end) {
                return nullptr;
            }
        }
        digits5and6 = 100;
        digits3and4 = digits1and2 / digits5and6;
        digits1and2 -= digits3and4 * digits5and6;
        *reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*> (text    ) = kDigits00To99[digits3and4];
        PRINT_PRINTED
        *reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*> (text + 2) = kDigits00To99[digits1and2];
        PRINT_PRINTED
        return text + 4;
    }
    else {
        if (text + 4 >= text_end) {
            return nullptr;
        }
        digits3and4 = 1000;
        if (digits1and2 >= digits3and4) {
            PRINTF ("\n    Range:[1000, 1023] length:4")
            digits1and2 -= digits3and4;
            text16 = reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*> (text + 2);
            *text16-- = kDigits00To99[digits1and2];
            PRINT_PRINTED
            *text16 = (((uint16_t)'1') | (((uint16_t)'0') << 8));
            PRINT_PRINTED
            return text + 4;
        }
        PRINTF ("\n    Range:[100, 999] length:3")
        digits1and2 = (uint16_t)value;
        digits3and4 = 100;
        digit = (char)(digits1and2 / digits3and4);
        digits1and2 -= digit * digits3and4;
        *text = digit + '0';
        PRINT_PRINTED
        *reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*> (text + 1) = kDigits00To99[digits1and2];
        PRINT_PRINTED
        return text + 3;
    }
}

}       //< namespace _
#undef  PRINTF
#undef  PRINT_PRINTED
#endif  //< MAJOR_SEAM >= 1 && MINOR_SEAM >= 1
```

### Author

- [Cale McCollough](https://calemccollough.github.io) <cale.mccollough@gmail.com>

Comment: FYI: By posting this on Stack Overflow you have irrevocably published it under [CC BY-SA 3.0](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) (per the Stack Exchange terms of use). Your statement that it's published under GPL 3 constitutes an *additional* license which a user could *optionally* use as an alternative to CC BY-SA 3.0. Which license to use is at the discretion of the user who copies the code. If this is an issue for you, I suggest you get competent legal advice. (IANAL) Note that there's nothing inherently wrong with this, but I figured it should be brought to your attention.

Comment: Very nice.  However it needs to return a `std::string` in order for the comparison to other methods listed here to be valid.  At first I couldn't figure out the use of the shift operator for the binary search tree, because a comparison is already exceptionally fast, but now I realize that it would be useful for precomputing that shifted value if you needed it.  You don't use it, though.  On the other hand, you don't end up with large literals encoded inside instructions, so maybe that's enough reason by itself.

Comment: I forgot to do that. It's just another wrapper function. All my stuff is Apache Licensed but I thought I'd try GNU but yeah... it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Okay, I changed the license back and added the string functions. Script is a socket-based family of languages for distributed computing to do my IGEEK on supercomputers with the Chinese Room. My string class is a ring buffer. {:-)-+=<  I've also got some really fast contiguous data structures that are much faster than JSON. I've got a dictionary, unordered map, tuple list, map, stack, an array that allows for data marshaling and byte-encoded scripts, JIT compiled text, and all kinds of VM goodness. It's not quite ready yet.

Comment: I just updated the algorithm and significantly improved performance of larger numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my little attempt of this fun puzzle.

Instead of using lookup tables, I wanted the compiler to figure it all out. In this case in particular - if you read Hackers' Delight, you see how divide and modulo work -- which makes it very possible to optimize that using SSE/AVX instructions.

**Performance benchmark**

As for speed, my benchmark here tells me it's 1,5 times faster than the work of Timo (on my Intel Haswell it runs on approximately 1 GB/s).

**Things you could consider a cheat**

As for the not-making-a-std-string cheat that I use -- of course I took that into consideration for my benchmark of Timo's method as well.

I do use an intrinsic: BSR. If you like, you can also use DeBruijn tables instead - which is one of the things I wrote quite a bit about on my 'fastest 2log' post. Of course, this does have a performance penalty (*well... if you're doing a lot of itoa operations you can actually make a faster BSR but I guess that's not fair...).

**The way it works**

First thing to do is figure out how much memory we need. This is basically a 10log, which can be implemented in a number of smart ways. See the frequently quoted "[Bit Twiddling Hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html)" for details.

Next thing to do is to execute the numeric output. I use template recursion for this, so the compiler will figure it out.

I use 'modulo' and 'div' right next to each other. If you read Hacker's Delight, you will notice that the two are closely related, so if you have one answer, you probably have the other as well. I figured the compiler can figure out the details... :-)

**The code**

Getting the number of digits using a (modified) log10:

```
struct logarithm
{
    static inline int log2(unsigned int value)
    {
        unsigned long index;
        if (!_BitScanReverse(&index, value))
        {
            return 0;
        }

        // add 1 if x is NOT a power of 2 (to do the ceil)
        return index + (value&(value - 1) ? 1 : 0);
    }

    static inline int numberDigits(unsigned int v)
    {
        static unsigned int const PowersOf10[] =
        { 0, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000, 100000000, 1000000000 };

        int t = (logarithm::log2(v) + 1) * 1233 >> 12; // (use a lg2 method from above)
        return 1 + t - (v < PowersOf10[t]);
    }
};
```

Getting yourself the string:

```
template <int count>
struct WriteHelper
{
    inline static void WriteChar(char* buf, unsigned int value)
    {
        unsigned int div = value / 10;
        unsigned int rem = value % 10;
        buf[count - 1] = rem + '0';

        WriteHelper<count - 1>::WriteChar(buf, div);
    }
};

template <>
struct WriteHelper<1>
{
    inline static void WriteChar(char* buf, unsigned int value) 
    {
        buf[0] = '0' + value;
    }
};

// Boring code that converts a length into a switch.
// TODO: Test if recursion with an 'if' is faster.
static inline void WriteNumber(char* data, int len, unsigned int val) 
{
    switch (len) {
    case 1:
        WriteHelper<1>::WriteChar(data, static_cast<unsigned int>(val));
        break;
    case 2:
        WriteHelper<2>::WriteChar(data, static_cast<unsigned int>(val));
        break;
    case 3:
        WriteHelper<3>::WriteChar(data, static_cast<unsigned int>(val));
        break;
    case 4:
        WriteHelper<4>::WriteChar(data, static_cast<unsigned int>(val));
        break;
    case 5:
        WriteHelper<5>::WriteChar(data, static_cast<unsigned int>(val));
        break;
    case 6:
        WriteHelper<6>::WriteChar(data, static_cast<unsigned int>(val));
        break;
    case 7:
        WriteHelper<7>::WriteChar(data, static_cast<unsigned int>(val));
        break;
    case 8:
        WriteHelper<8>::WriteChar(data, static_cast<unsigned int>(val));
        break;
    case 9:
        WriteHelper<9>::WriteChar(data, static_cast<unsigned int>(val));
        break;
    case 10:
        WriteHelper<10>::WriteChar(data, static_cast<unsigned int>(val));
        break;
    }
}

// The main method you want to call...
static int Write(char* data, int val) 
{
    int len;
    if (val >= 0) 
    {
        len = logarithm::numberDigits(val);
        WriteNumber(data, len, unsigned int(val));
        return len;
    }
    else 
    {
        unsigned int v(-val);
        len = logarithm::numberDigits(v);
        WriteNumber(data+1, len, v);
        data[0] = '-';
        return len + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Interestingly, I recently gave a copy of Hacker's Delight to a coworker.  Any particular sections?  Of course, note that modulo and div, although both returned from a single divide instruction, will not be obtained that way, because division by a constant is implemented much faster using hardware multiply than divide.

Comment: @BenVoigt actually if you run 'disassemble' on VS2013 you get exactly the code you would expect after reading H's delight. The chapter you're looking for is chapter 10.

Comment: Yes, that's the implementation using hardware multiply I was referring to.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes of course, that was what I meant. Both modulo and multiply (by constant) use the same magic number, shift (arith and normal). My assumption here was that the compiler is able to figure out it is emitting the same instructions multiple times and optimize that - and since all operations can be vectorized, it might figure that out as well (let's call that a bonus :-). My point with H's delight was that if you know how these operations are compiled (integer multiply, shift), you can make these assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

Modification to user434507's solution.  Modified to use character array instead of C++ string.  Runs a bit faster.  Also moved the check for 0 lower in the code...as this never happens for my particular case.  Move it back if it's more common for your case.

```
// Int2Str.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "StopWatch.h"

using namespace std;

const char digit_pairs[201] = {
  "00010203040506070809"
  "10111213141516171819"
  "20212223242526272829"
  "30313233343536373839"
  "40414243444546474849"
  "50515253545556575859"
  "60616263646566676869"
  "70717273747576777879"
  "80818283848586878889"
  "90919293949596979899"
};

void itostr(int n, char* c) {
    int sign = -(n<0);
    unsigned int val = (n^sign)-sign;

    int size;
    if(val>=10000) {
        if(val>=10000000) {
            if(val>=1000000000) {
                size=10;
            }
            else if(val>=100000000) {
                size=9;
            }
            else size=8;
        }
        else {
            if(val>=1000000) {
                size=7;
            }
            else if(val>=100000) {
                size=6;
            }
            else size=5;
        }
    }
    else {
        if(val>=100) {
            if(val>=1000) {
                size=4;
            }
            else size=3;
        }
        else {
            if(val>=10) {
                size=2;
            }
            else if(n==0) {
                c[0]='0';
                c[1] = '\0';
                return;
            }
            else size=1;
        }
    }
    size -= sign;
    if(sign)
    *c='-';

    c += size-1;
    while(val>=100) {
        int pos = val % 100;
        val /= 100;
        *(short*)(c-1)=*(short*)(digit_pairs+2*pos); 
        c-=2;
    }
    while(val>0) {
        *c--='0' + (val % 10);
        val /= 10;
    }
    c[size+1] = '\0';
}

void itostr(unsigned val, char* c)
{
    int size;
    if(val>=10000)
    {
        if(val>=10000000)
        {
            if(val>=1000000000)
                size=10;
            else if(val>=100000000)
                size=9;
            else 
                size=8;
        }
        else
        {
            if(val>=1000000)
                size=7;
            else if(val>=100000)
                size=6;
            else
                size=5;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        if(val>=100)
        {
            if(val>=1000)
                size=4;
            else
                size=3;
        }
        else
        {
            if(val>=10)
                size=2;
            else if (val==0) {
                c[0]='0';
                c[1] = '\0';
                return;
            }
            else
                size=1;
        }
    }

    c += size-1;
    while(val>=100)
    {
       int pos = val % 100;
       val /= 100;
       *(short*)(c-1)=*(short*)(digit_pairs+2*pos); 
       c-=2;
    }
    while(val>0)
    {
        *c--='0' + (val % 10);
        val /= 10;
    }
    c[size+1] = '\0';
}

void test() {
    bool foundmismatch = false;
    char str[16];
    char compare[16];
    for(int i = -1000000; i < 1000000; i++) {
        int random = rand();
        itostr(random, str);
        itoa(random, compare, 10);
        if(strcmp(str, compare) != 0) {
            cout << "Mismatch found: " << endl;
            cout << "Generated: " << str << endl;
            cout << "Reference: " << compare << endl;
            foundmismatch = true;
        }
    }
    if(!foundmismatch) {
        cout << "No mismatch found!" << endl;
    }
    cin.get();
}

void benchmark() {
    StopWatch stopwatch;
    stopwatch.setup("Timer");
    stopwatch.reset();
    stopwatch.start();
    char str[16];
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 2000000; i++) {
        itostr(i, str);
    }
    stopwatch.stop();
    cin.get();
}

int main( int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    benchmark();
}
```

Comment: I've tested it from 0x80000000 to 0x7FFFFFFF and already at -999999999 you get invalid values (I've stopped after a few mismatches). 

`Mismatch found:
Generated: -9999999990
Reference: -999999999

Mismatch found:
Generated: -9999999980
Reference: -999999998

Mismatch found:
Generated: -9999999970
Reference: -999999997`

Answer (score 1):

We use the following code (for MSVC):

Templated tBitScanReverse:

```
#include <intrin.h>

namespace intrin {

#pragma intrinsic(_BitScanReverse)
#pragma intrinsic(_BitScanReverse64)

template<typename TIntegerValue>
__forceinline auto tBitScanReverse(DWORD * out_index, TIntegerValue mask)
    -> std::enable_if_t<(std::is_integral<TIntegerValue>::value && sizeof(TIntegerValue) == 4), unsigned char>
{
    return _BitScanReverse(out_index, mask);
}
template<typename TIntegerValue>
__forceinline auto tBitScanReverse(DWORD * out_index, TIntegerValue mask)
    -> std::enable_if_t<(std::is_integral<TIntegerValue>::value && sizeof(TIntegerValue) == 8), unsigned char>
{
#if !(_M_IA64 || _M_AMD64)
    auto res = _BitScanReverse(out_index, (unsigned long)(mask >> 32));
    if (res) {
        out_index += 32;
        return res;
    }
    return _BitScanReverse(out_index, (unsigned long)mask);
#else
    return _BitScanReverse64(out_index, mask);
#endif
}

}
```

char/wchar_t helpers:

```
template<typename TChar> inline constexpr TChar   ascii_0();
template<>               inline constexpr char    ascii_0() { return  '0'; }
template<>               inline constexpr wchar_t ascii_0() { return L'0'; }

template<typename TChar, typename TInt> inline constexpr TChar ascii_DEC(TInt d) { return (TChar)(ascii_0<TChar>() + d); }
```

Powers of 10 tables:

```
static uint32 uint32_powers10[] = {
    1,
    10,
    100,
    1000,
    10000,
    100000,
    1000000,
    10000000,
    100000000,
    1000000000
//   123456789
};
static uint64 uint64_powers10[] = {
    1ULL,
    10ULL,
    100ULL,
    1000ULL,
    10000ULL,
    100000ULL,
    1000000ULL,
    10000000ULL,
    100000000ULL,
    1000000000ULL,
    10000000000ULL,
    100000000000ULL,
    1000000000000ULL,
    10000000000000ULL,
    100000000000000ULL,
    1000000000000000ULL,
    10000000000000000ULL,
    100000000000000000ULL,
    1000000000000000000ULL,
    10000000000000000000ULL
//   1234567890123456789
};

template<typename TUint> inline constexpr const TUint  * powers10();
template<>               inline constexpr const uint32 * powers10() { return uint32_powers10; }
template<>               inline constexpr const uint64 * powers10() { return uint64_powers10; }
```

Actual print:

```
template<typename TChar, typename TUInt>
__forceinline auto
print_dec(
    TUInt u,
    TChar * & buffer) -> typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned<TUInt>::value>
{
    if (u < 10) {                                                   // 1-digit, including 0  
        *buffer++ = ascii_DEC<TChar>(u);
    }
    else {
        DWORD log2u;
        intrin::tBitScanReverse(&log2u, u);                         //  log2u [3,31]  (u >= 10)
        DWORD log10u = ((log2u + 1) * 77) >> 8;                     //  log10u [1,9]   77/256 = ln(2) / ln(10)
        DWORD digits = log10u + (u >= powers10<TUInt>()[log10u]);   //  digits [2,10]

        buffer += digits;
        auto p = buffer;

        for (--digits; digits; --digits) {
            auto x = u / 10, d = u - x * 10;
            *--p = ascii_DEC<TChar>(d);
            u = x;
        }
        *--p = ascii_DEC<TChar>(u);
    }
}
```

Last loop can be unrolled:

```
switch (digits) {
case 10: { auto x = u / 10, d = u - x * 10; *--p = ascii_DEC<TChar>(d); u = x; }
case  9: { auto x = u / 10, d = u - x * 10; *--p = ascii_DEC<TChar>(d); u = x; }
case  8: { auto x = u / 10, d = u - x * 10; *--p = ascii_DEC<TChar>(d); u = x; }
case  7: { auto x = u / 10, d = u - x * 10; *--p = ascii_DEC<TChar>(d); u = x; }
case  6: { auto x = u / 10, d = u - x * 10; *--p = ascii_DEC<TChar>(d); u = x; }
case  5: { auto x = u / 10, d = u - x * 10; *--p = ascii_DEC<TChar>(d); u = x; }
case  4: { auto x = u / 10, d = u - x * 10; *--p = ascii_DEC<TChar>(d); u = x; }
case  3: { auto x = u / 10, d = u - x * 10; *--p = ascii_DEC<TChar>(d); u = x; }
case  2: { auto x = u / 10, d = u - x * 10; *--p = ascii_DEC<TChar>(d); u = x; *--p = ascii_DEC<TChar>(u); break; }
default: __assume(0);
}
```

The main idea is the same as @atlaste suggested before: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29039967/2204001

Answer (score 1):

Just came across this because of recent activity; I don't really have time to add benchmarks, but I wanted to add what I wrote in the past for when I need fast integer to string conversion...

https://github.com/CarloWood/ai-utils/blob/master/itoa.h
https://github.com/CarloWood/ai-utils/blob/master/itoa.cxx

The trick used here is the user must provide a std::array that is large
enough (on their stack) and that this code writes the string into that
backwards, starting at the units, and then returning a pointer into the array with an offset to where the result actually starts.

This therefore doesn't allocate or move memory, but it still requires a division and modulo per result digit (which I believe to be fast enough as that is merely code run internally on the CPU; memory access is usually the problem imho).

Answer (score -1):

Why is nobody using the div function from stdlib when both, quotient and remainder are needed?
Using Timo's source code, I ended up with something like this:

```
if(val >= 0)
{
    div_t   d2 = div(val,100);
    while(d2.quot)
    {
        COPYPAIR(it,2 * d2.rem);
        it-=2;
        d2 = div(d2.quot,100);
    }
    COPYPAIR(it,2*d2.rem);
    if(d2.quot<10)
        it++;
}
else
{
    div_t   d2 = div(val,100);
    while(d2.quot)
    {
        COPYPAIR(it,-2 * d2.rem);
        it-=2;
        d2 = div(d2.quot,100);
    }
    COPYPAIR(it,-2*d2.rem);
    if(d2.quot<=-10)
        it--;
    *it = '-';
}
```

Ok, for unsigned int's, the div function can't be used but unsigned's can be handled separate.
I've defined the COPYPAIR macro as follows to test variations how to copy the 2 characters from the digit_pairs (found no obvious advantage of any of these methods):

```
#define COPYPAIR0(_p,_i) { memcpy((_p), &digit_pairs[(_i)], 2); }
#define COPYPAIR1(_p,_i) { (_p)[0] = digit_pairs[(_i)]; (_p)[1] = digit_pairs[(_i)+1]; }
#define COPYPAIR2(_p,_i) { unsigned short * d = (unsigned short *)(_p); unsigned short * s = (unsigned short *)&digit_pairs[(_i)]; *d = *s; }

#define COPYPAIR COPYPAIR2
```

Comment: It's because this challenge is about speed, not the fewest lines of code.

Comment: PS: And for the people that want to use this in my solution: (1) it's much much slower and (2) because div works on _signed_ integers - which breaks abs(INT32_MIN).