# C++ string literals vs. const strings

Tags: c++, string, constants, literals

I know that string literals in C/C++ have *static storage duration*, meaning that they live "forever", i.e. as long as the program runs.

Thus, if I have a function that is being called very frequently and uses a string literal like so:

```
void foo(int val)
{
    std::stringstream s;
    s << val;
    lbl->set_label("Value: " + s.str());
}
```

where the set_label function takes a `const std::string&` as a parameter.

Should I be using a `const std::string` here instead of the string literal or would it make no difference?

I need to minimise as much runtime memory consumption as possible.

edit:

I meant to compare the string literal with a `const std::string prefix("Value: ");` that is initialized in some sort of a constants header file.

Also, the concatenation here returns a temporary (let us call it `Value: 42` and a const reference to this temporary is being passed to the function `set_text()`, am I correct in this?

Thank you again!

Comment: What's your magic 8 ball say?

Comment: If you want to minimize runtime memory consumption, how about modifying set_label to take a const char * and use a char * instead of a string?

Comment: @user347594: I can't modify `set_label` unfortunately

Comment: @Noah: Having a const string would greatly increase the maintainability of the code, but I will sacrifice that for memory optimizations for this application, hence my question =)

Comment: Since you say this function is being called very frequently, you probably don't want to use `stringstream`, which is very VERY slow.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351371/c-performance-challenge-integer-to-stdstring-conversion.

Comment: Besides, `stringstream` (along with `stringbuf` and all the other support machinery) is waaaay more of a memory hog than the difference between `char*` and `std::string`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your program operates on the same literal every time. There is no more efficient form of storage. A std::string would be constructed, duplicated on the heap, then freed every time the function runs, which would be a total waste.

Comment: Unless you know what implementation the OP's using, you can't know that this isn't exactly what's happening anyway nor that compiler optimizations won't render your statement completely false.

Comment: Noah is right, a small string like this may not use heap storage at all.  `stringstream` on the other hand is very heavyweight...

Comment: @Noah: I'm quite sure that no matter how the compiler optimizes, it can't come up with something more efficient than a literal string.

Comment: @DeadMG would using a string literal be better than using a `const std::string` defined in a constants header file or does it make no difference?

Comment: @vic: It really doesn't matter. A string literal is statically allocated once and referred to forever after. There is no possible way of storing that data in a more efficient fashion, end of story.

Comment: @DeadMG: No there's no more efficient storage for the character data, but you need to use templates to access that string literal efficiently.  If you let it decay to a `const char*`, then finding the length becomes O(N), while getting the length of a `std::string` is O(1).

Comment: @Ben: I know. The OP specified runtime memory usage, so I really don't care.

Comment: @DeadMG: Yeah, some of the reply comments say "performant" or "efficiency" but the question only asks to "minimize memory consumption".  OTOH, a string literal passed to `operator+(const std::string&, const std::string&)`, as is done here, will use no less memory than a reference to a global `std::string`.

Comment: @Ben: Doesn't std::string have operator+ overloads for const char*? As for efficiency, there is memory efficiency as well as time efficiency.

Comment: @DeadMG: You're right of course, the code in the question would call `operator+(const char*, std::string&)`, but since that can't infer the length like a template could, it has to measure it, which at least temporarily uses more memory than a `std::string`.  The difference in memory usage is so minuscule either way that I tend to move directly to speed concerns.

Comment: @Ben: Me too. There's no `template<size_t size> operator+(const char(&)[size], const std::string&)`? That seems an unnecessary oversight.

Comment: @DeadMG: That's exactly what I was talking about... and it appears that there isn't even a `std::string` constructor that accepts a character array like that, nor is one added in C++0x (not sure whether `initializer_list` gives the same advantages).  It would seem that the performance of `operator+` could be increased considerably by providing a constructor that accepts an array by reference, and an additional parameter which is the size to reserve so that the call to `append` won't cause reallocation.

Answer (score 2):

This will use less memory and run much faster (use `snprintf` if your compiler supports it):

```
void foo(int val)
{
    char msg[32];
    lbl->set_label(std::string(msg, sprintf(msg, "Value: %d", val)));
}
```

For even faster implementations, check out [C++ performance challenge: integer to std::string conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351371/c-performance-challenge-integer-to-stdstring-conversion)

Comment: +1 for the optimization! Coming back to my original question though, would a string literal be more perfomant than using a `const std::string` defined in a constants header file?

Comment: @vic: It really depends whether you need the length.  `std::string` caches the length, so it's a small matter of reading a variable, while with a `char*` you have to use `strlen` which iterates.  However, the string literal itself is a character array which carries its length as part of the compile-time type information, which is the fastest of all (when the code is written to take advantage of it).

Comment: You missed a parenthesis in your answer. +1 anyway. I like the solution.

Comment: @whoan: Thanks for bringing that to my attention.

Answer (score 0):

How will you build your const std::string ? If you do it from some string literral, in the end it will just be *worse* (or identical if compiler does a good job). A string literal does not consumes much memory, and also static memory, that may not be the kind of memory you are low of.

If you can read all your string literals from, say a file, and give the memory back to OS when the strings are not used any more, there may be some way to reduce memory footprint (but it will probably slow the program much).

But there is probably many other ways to reduce memory consumption before doing that kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Store them in some kind of resource and load/unload them as necessary.