# How to assign the value of an array of strings to "Name" + #, eg. Name1, Name2, Name3, etc.. C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I'm trying to do something like this: `Name[i] = "Name" + (i+1)` in a forloop, so that the values of the array will be: `Name[0] = Name1`, `Name[1] = Name2`, `Name[2] = Name3`.

Is there an easier way to do this beside converting the value of `i` to a `char` and add it to the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using C++2011 you can also use `std::to_string()`:

```
name[i] = "Name" + std::to_string(i + 1);
```

This should avoid the need to create a string stream.

Comment: And if your compiler doesn't provide it yet, you can find several different implementations to choose from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351371/c-performance-challenge-integer-to-stdstring-conversion)

Answer (score 1):

That's what `std::stringstream` is for:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "Name" << (i+1);

...

name[i] = ss.str();
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason not to use `std::ostringstream`? (note the funny `o` after `std::`)

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Any particular reason *to* use it?

Comment: The object is simpler and somewhat faster to construct although `std::istream` doesn't really add any members. Since the open mode is passed to the `std::stringbuf` this class can avoid some set up if it knows that it will only be used for input or output (although most implementations ignore this). Finally, it states what the stream is actually used for (well, I managed to use `i` when I mean `o`).

Comment: @DietmarKühl: The only reason I can think of is that [it's slower than molasses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351371/c-performance-challenge-integer-to-stdstring-conversion).  Hopefully this isn't a big enough chunk of the overall program to matter.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It worked! I'm not that familiar with stringstream. I will learn more about it.