# Base 10 to base n conversions

Tags: c++, algorithm, base-conversion

I'm trying to write a C++ program that does base-conversions.

I want to convert a decimal number to all the other integer bases from 2 to 20.

Is there an efficient and easy-to-implement algorithm for base conversions?

Comment: there is only one way to convert numbers from one to another base. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: When you say "all the other bases from 2 to 20", I'm going to assume you mean all of the real integer bases from 2 to 20?  No unreal bases, and no non-integer bases?  Those are harder.

Comment: Also, what's the problem?  Show us the code you have so far.

Comment: @MooingDuck Yes, you can assume that

Comment: @MooingDuck I don't ask for source code, but for an efficient algorithm

Comment: What have you tried? What's "difficult" about the algorithms that you have found?

Comment: Also keep in mind that a number is a number, and numbers are not inherently in any base, including base 10.  Computers store these numbers in base 2, but it's still _just a number_ in C++ (unless you do binary operations on it)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I'm planning to use a `std::string` instead

Comment: A quick google search finds many many pages showing how to do this.  Here's one: http://mathbits.com/MathBits/CompSci/Introduction/frombase10.htm

Comment: Do you plan to use strings because you'd like to do conversion on numbers of arbitrary magnitude?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yes, but not only that. I would like to be able to represent numbers from base n where n > 10. For that reason I am going to need strings.

Comment: @RondogiannisAristophanes Ah, that's not what I meant: of course you need strings to represent your input and output. I was asking if any of the numbers that you plan to convert would be greater than 2000000000 when represented in decimal system, in which case implementing the algorithm becomes significantly more complex.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Sorry, misunderstood. No the numbers will be up to 40000.

Comment: An implementation is available as an example usage of div at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/div

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I don't understand where exactly is the problem? It's very easy and straigtforward to do base conversion: you do it as you would by hand.

- divide the *number* by *base*
- write down the remainder
- repeat the process with the integer part of the division
- stop when you reach zero
- the remainders in reverse order give you the digits in *base*

Example:

1025 (decimal) to base 15:

```
1025 / 15 = 68 , remainder 5
68   / 15 =  4 , remainder 8
4    / 15 =  0 , remainder 4
```

The number in base 15 is 485

Comment: Fantastic straight to the point answer. Love it!

Answer (score 3):

You may have two problems:

- Parsing from the original base to the computer's native integer representation (`strtol` is quite good at this).
- Formatting into the new base. (`itoa` is quite good at this).

If you want to write it yourself, you might like the [`div` function](http://linux.die.net/man/3/div).  You feed in the number and the base, and it splits off the rightmost digit.  Repeat to get all digits.

If you want to be more efficient, you can divide by the base squared, and get two digits at a time (use a lookup table to get the ASCII characters for both digits).  [Here's an example of some very efficient implementations.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351371/c-performance-challenge-integer-to-stdstring-conversion)  Changing it to use a different base would not be difficult.