# Write a C++ program to convert decimal to arbitrary bases

Tags: numbers, decimal, system

I have problem with my assignment. I need help to write a program to convert a decimal to base 5, 7, 16.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. We will help you with the code if you have any specific problem, but we will not do your homework for you. Please show us what you have tried and what problems you faced.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Base 10 to base n conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12713999/base-10-to-base-n-conversions)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.