# FAST DMA benefit from FPGA using threads in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, dma

I am transferring data from FPGA PCIe thru DMA, which is very fast. I have 500 data with each data comprise of 80000 BYTES. Hence the time for all 500 data receiving and saving in .bin file is 0.5 seconds. If I do the same in .txt file (which is my final goal) it takes 15 seconds.

Hence Now what I want is to use threads in c++, where 1 thread (I call it as master thread) take DMA data(single data at a time) and simultaneously open the 500 other threads (one for each file) each file saving thread wait for some trigger event etc. (not much idea, since CPU inherently runs in sequential manner, causing problem for an FPGA designer who deals in parallel domain)

Please see the case I have explained could be the solution, but I need to know how to implement it if it is correct in++  ????

**case**

***1st data(thru DMA) comes in master thread (where global memory is assigned using malloc() ) -> thread for file 1 is waiting for any TRIGGER etc. and as soon as it gets this trigger, copy the memory contents to its own allocated  memory and then starts saving in the file, meanwhile it also triggers the 'master thread' to increment its counter and receive the next data and the process continues for the whole 500 data.***

I am mostly and FPGA guy and c++ at this high level is first time, I am determined but am stuck. really messed up for two days reading loads of material over threads (in c++) mainly starting from createthreads() and going on and on, I thought the WaitForSingleObject might be solution but I cannot understand how to implement this...

any idea would be appreciable. I do not seek any code, I just seek the way to implement. For example those familiar with VHDL, they might know in VHDL we can use

Code: `wait until abc'event and abc = '1';`

but what to do here?

Thanks
sraza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance measurement you give show that the problem has nothing to do with DMA or threads.  What's slow is converting from binary to string data.

Not surprising, since [C++ iostreams are miserably slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340396/does-the-c-standard-mandate-poor-performance-for-iostreams-or-am-i-just-deali) and [even the C stdio functions are significantly suboptimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351371/c-performance-challenge-integer-to-stdstring-conversion)

Use an optimized function for number->string conversion, and your 15 second time for writing a text file will get a lot closer to that 0.5 second time you have for binary.  I'd expect 1.0 seconds or less, from this single change.

Comment: (Note: I'd expect the approach you outlined in your question to make performance even worse, if only because now all your files are fragmented instead of continuous)