# Return char * instead of string

Tags: c++, c, char, malloc, cstring

I am trying to use 'user434507''s unsigned solution here:

[C++ performance challenge: integer to std::string conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351371/c-performance-challenge-integer-to-stdstring-conversion)

but instead I want it to return a char * and not accept in a string.

I have been playing around with it for awhile and this is what I have got, but it just returns nothing/garbage  - My limited C and pointer knowledge is not helping me. I think I am using malloc right, but in his original code it's as if he uses an internal char* and just changed the elements of a string and returns the string. I figured if I allocated via malloc it would have the same effect :

```
char * itostr(unsigned val)
{

    const char digit_pairs[201] = {
      "00010203040506070809"
      "10111213141516171819"
      "20212223242526272829"
      "30313233343536373839"
      "40414243444546474849"
      "50515253545556575859"
      "60616263646566676869"
      "70717273747576777879"
      "80818283848586878889"
      "90919293949596979899"
    };

    int size;
    if(val>=10000) {
        if(val>=10000000) {
            if(val>=1000000000) {
                size=10;
            } else if(val>=100000000) {
                size=9;
            } else {
                size=8;
            }
        } else {
            if(val>=1000000) {
                size=7;
            } else if(val>=100000) {
                size=6;
            } else {
                size=5;
            }
        }
    } else {
        if(val>=100) {
            if(val>=1000) {
                size=4;
            } else {
                size=3;
            }
        } else {
            if(val>=10) {
                size=2;
            } else {
                size=1;
            }
        }
    }

    char * c = (char *)malloc(size + 1);
    c[size] = '\0';

    //char* c = &s[size-1];
    while(val>=100)
    {
       int pos = val % 100;
       val /= 100;
       *(short*)(c-1)=*(short*)(digit_pairs+2*pos); 
       c-=2;
    }
    while(val>0)
    {
        *c--='0' + (val % 10);
        val /= 10;
    }


    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
c += size-1;
```

You need this line just before the first `while` loop. The two loops write the digits from right to left. It's needed so that writing starts at the right end of the string.

Comment: That line isn't in his overloaded unsigned function. But I do see it in his signed one.

Comment: `char* c = &s[size-1];` in the unsigned version does the same thing. `c` starts out pointing at the `size-1`th array index.

Comment: I added `c += size-1;` just before my while loop and it's not helping.

Comment: Figured out my issue. I never kept track of the original location and returned that.